# How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?

Tags: system-installation

I just want to delete EVERYTHING except maybe `/home` folder and reinstall everything, because system became a little bit slow and I want to do that when 14.04 comes out. What's the best way to do that?

At the moment I have 12.04 and have some other systems (cinamon, lubuntu etc.) that I want gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you re-install Ubuntu over an existing older version depends on if you have `/home` in a separate partition or as a folder within `/` partition, the default.

In either case you start the installation process from a live DVD/USB. Proceed until you come to the **Installation Type** page.

[image]

**If you have `/home` in its default location within `/` partition:**

Choose the option: **Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.** This will keep your `/home` folder. Even though it says "installed software will be kept where possible," in my experience it cleared most of them. YMMV.

**If you have `/home` in its own separate partition:**

You can either go with the above choice.

Or you can choose **Something else.** If you choose "Something else," make sure you check the format box for the `/` partition and uncheck the format box for `/home` partition. See below for an example.

[image]

Note, in this picture above both the `/` and `/home` partitions are to be formatted. Make sure that **the format box for `/home` is unchecked** before you proceed. Otherwise you will lose all your data!

This method will format the `/` partition and all the extra programs you had installed in the older version will be gone. However, the settings saved in the `/home` will remain. If you decide to re-install some of them, say Chrome, your personal configuration, if any, should be there for the new installation to use.

**Removing Cinamon and Lubuntu**

It depends on how you installed Cinamon Lubuntu etc.

If you had installed just the cinamon desktop environments (DE) and the LXDE (the DE for Lubuntu) on top of Ubuntu via **Ubuntu Software Center**, or the `apt-get` command, then yes. Either method will delete them.

If you installed these from their own LiveDVD/CD/USB in separate partitions, then no. In that case you will have to remove those partitions first. You can remove these partitions either from the LiveDVD/USB, by choosing the option **Try before installing** and then using **gparted.** Make sure you don't delete the wrong partitions. At this stage you can move the other partitions around if needed and reallocate the empty space to the version of Ubuntu you want to keep.

Hope this helps

Comment: When using Something Else partions are _not_ set be formatted by default. You need to click Change, choose the to use/mount a partition, and then check or not check format.

Comment: @user68186 will it delete cinamon, lubuntu etc.? also, will system become faster you think? thanks

Comment: @mrSuperEvening It depends on how you installed cinamon lubuntu etc. If you had installed just the cinamon desktop environments (DE) and the LXDE on top of Ubuntu via **Ubuntu Software Center**, or the `apt-get` command, then yes. Either method will delete them. If you installed these from their own LiveDVD/CD/USB in separate partitions, then no. In that case you will have to remove those partitions first and reallocate the empty space to Ubuntu during the **Something else** stage of reinstall.

Comment: @user68186: and do you think system will become faster? thanks.

Comment: This is hard to say. In general Linux does not become slow over time in my experience like Windows. However, I have experienced slowdown at start-up and shut-down after I had installed something. So it is possible removing all the old stuff will make it faster. If you search for upgrade versus fresh install, you will find many prefer a fresh install to reduce the accumulated junk. In any case, 14.04 is supposed to be faster than 12.04. So it will be hard to say in the end.

Answer (score 8):

**What if you're using a *modern* release of Ubuntu Desktop ([*or flavor*](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours)) and don't see an Upgrade/Repair existing installation option?**

The option still exists on releases up to and including Ubuntu 22.10, but it's not offered as an easy to click option, and needs to be *manually triggered*.

This option will allow you to

- repair an installation (ie. *re-install the same release*)
- upgrade to a later release (ie. *next release, or even skip releases*)
- go backwards to a prior release (ie. *you didn't like a later release, and want to revert to something older; though there can be consequences with this, which I won't cover, but it's possible & problems will not occur in many cases; issues are package level basis, so do your homework before you expect a backwards install will be good for you*)
- you're installing a Ubuntu system over a non-Ubuntu, but other GNU/Linux OS, this will work too (*within limits*).

Assuming you're using a Desktop installer (namely `ubiquity` (used by Ubuntu Desktop & many *flavors*, including Kubuntu which uses a different *skin* which changes how it looks), or `calamares` (used by *modern* Lubuntu or Ubuntu-Studio)) this will work.  I'm not covering a *di* (Debian installer for server or desktop *alternate* ISO) or `subiquity` server installer, you will

- Choose the Manual option, which may appear as

  - Something Else
  - Manual Partitioning

- Select your existing partition(s).

Note:   You do **not** need to have a separate /home partition for Ubuntu Desktop to have your settings & datafiles survive re-install; this works equally with a single partition for all *supported* releases of Ubuntu (most *unsupported* too).

Ensure you DO NOT format any, the lack of format for "/" is what triggers the **REPAIR** or **RE-INSTALL** option I'm talking about here.

The installer will

- take note of your *manually installed* packages  (ie. *those you added to your system post-install*)
- erase system directories  (*if you have some server apps installed; as they store configs in system directories, you may suffer loss here, but it won't impact desktop applications*)
- install the new system (*from your booted live media*)
- if internet is available install the extra packages noted earlier
- ask to reboot (*and won’t touch any user files unless you formatted*)

This is QA (*Quality Assurance*) tested to work with all Ubuntu repository software only (not 3rd party), so no guarantees are offered with 3rd party, and I'm choosing to ignore 3rd party apps for this 'answer'.

The user is asked to reboot, where you'll be able to login & see your older desktop configs, the additional apps (*manually installed* packages you'd added) also re-installed, and be able to load your favorite music player & continue playing your existing playlists as if the re-install didn't occur.

(*FYI:  I use `clementine` as example in the [Understanding Lubuntu QA Testcases](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) document as it's a non-standard app for Lubuntu, and thus allows me to confirm it got re-installed correctly as I perform other post-install checks during QA; all your Ubuntu repository apps should re-install where available*).

**Notes**:

I've used this to *migrate* a Fedora system to Ubuntu, as well as an older OpenSuSE Leap system to Ubuntu.  As Fedora & OpenSuSE are *rpm* based (not *deb* based), no *manually installed* packages will get auto-reinstalled.  ie. this will work for converting any GNU/Linux system to Ubuntu, as long as the Ubuntu installer can cope with the *file-system* that is used.

I've also used it for Debian systems very regularly, though as packages never really align for Debian & Ubuntu, I'd suggest erasing system directories manually prior to the install process to avoid having the re-install attempt to re-install packages for the non-Ubuntu system that cannot be found (ie. avoiding the error messages on unfound packages). If your system was a non-Ubuntu system, please do **not** file bugs on unfound packages (*such bug reports will be invalid*).

I've also used this to switch a Linux Mint system to Ubuntu. Before I trust a new (*second hand*) box I use it for a week or two before I start my real install.  I used Linux Mint (& FreeBSD as I dual boot systems) to test my old *primary* box during this '*hardware*' testing, but decided there was some pieces of the Linux Mint I really liked & wanted to survive into my install, so I opted to do an *unclean* install instead of my intended *clean* (ie. format) install. As I wanted a clean package system (no Linux Mint packages attempted to be re-installed), I just erased all system directories that contained data I didn't want to survive, so the install of Ubuntu (17.10 at the time) didn't detect a prior OS, but without format, the parts I wanted to survive remained.  FYI:  The FreeBSD system used a non-Ubuntu compatible file-system, thus I didn't attempt to re-use that & did a format install over that system.

I'm involved with QA, as well as heavily involved with one *flavor* in particular, thus keep systems of all *supported* releases available for support reasons. For many of those, I never actually perform the normal upgrades of packages, but use this install method to re-install as it accomplishes two tasks at once, ie. a QA test is performed & I check it still works for *unreleased* media, as well as updating the packages on my *support* installs.  Currently the releases that get this approach are *jammy* (currently using 22.04.2 *daily* media; ie. unreleased) & *lunar*. When I no longer need an install for support, I'll use this install method to convert it to another release (ie. *21.10 reached EOL, that install became 22.10 as I already had a 22.04 system*)

I like to think of this ***Repair Installation*** option as *Upgrade via re-install*, though Lubuntu refer to it as *Upgrade using existing partition*.  I tend to think of this as my backup for *release-upgrades* if I lack time, don't have sufficient disk space (as system directories are wiped, no downloads occurs; a pretty full disk isn't the issue it is with normal *release-upgrades*), or just if I lack the time to do the *release-upgrade*.

It can be used with **encryption**, though I won't support it with *full disk encryption* (*very easy to make mistakes here*); if your system uses Data Partition encryption (*home folder which used to be a default install for older releases like 17.10 I mentioned earlier*), you can still use this install method very easily.  For home partition encryption, you need only to add the encryption packages (*not default any more thus not included on modern ISOs*) to the *live* system **prior to starting the installer**, then start the installer & install normally.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 is expected to use the new Desktop Installer (called *canary* for prior releases), where I've not **yet** had a successful install using this install method,  but it's hoped & expected that will be rectified prior to Ubuntu *lunar* becoming Ubuntu 23.04.  Don't expect this install method to work with older releases though if using the *canary* installer.

Comment: Further to last comment; I've now had successful a successful re-install with the new *Ubuntu Desktop installer* too using Ubuntu *lunar* (or 23.04).  I'm writing the latest ISO currently to test that again...

Comment: Do note:  There can be differences between releases if using this install method and Ubuntu Desktop with `universe` packages involved (*which I suspect most of us use*).  As *flavors* have 'universe' installed by default there is no issue, but Ubuntu Desktop does **not** have it *enabled* by default; thus if you want 'universe' packages to install, you **may** need to add that repository & `sudo apt update` prior to starting the installer for many releases where using Ubuntu Desktop (*if you want those to re-install automatically*).  This is not required for all releases though.

Comment: A problem has been encountered during *noble* QA and it maybe this re-install feature will be disabled for *noble* ; at least at release (it maybe able to be fixed as `subiquity` can be upgraded without re-spinning ISOs).. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-provision/+bug/2058638/comments/5  Where 23.04 & 23.10 had `ubiquity` ISOs available as alternatives; Ubuntu Desktop & many flavors will only have `ubuntu-desktop-installer` for *noble*

Answer (score 3):

Just reinstall it over itself.

Ubuntu will not touch your data in `/home` and you'll start off with a clean slate. Just ensure that "Format" is not selected in your partition screen.

You can reinstall it in the same fashion as you installed:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Let me reiterate to ensure that you **do not reformat your partition**! And as with all system upgrades and reinstalls, having a fresh backup is always a good precaution to take.

You might have some things in your home directory that could be leading to performance degradation. In the past I've had config files in my home directory in directories like `.gconf` and `.gnome` that ended to get large and unweildy. These days things like that aren't as much of an issue.

Comment: how? Just with usb? Thanks.

Comment: yep, just how you did it when you installed ubuntu the first time

Comment: @user68186 Feel free to just add that information into the answer!

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCastro, I decided to post my own answer, elaborating on the comments above (now removed).

Comment: @JorgeCastro will it delete cinamon, lubuntu etc.? also, will system become faster you think? thanks