# Replace Mint with Ubuntu in dual booting system

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10, mint

I am already dual booting windows 10 with Linux Mint, and I am trying to replace Mint with Ubuntu. I have already created a bootable usb for Ubuntu.

When I try to install Ubuntu, I don't see any option to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10. Rather, I see "install Ubuntu alongside Linux Mint". I didn't find any option to keep my windows 10. How can I replace Mint with Ubuntu in this dual boot system? Mint is installed on an ext4 partition and I have a Linux swap partition.

Comment: Do you want to have Mint, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15 on your system or replace Mint with Ubuntu 15?

Comment: Just replace mint by ubuntu  .

Comment: All that you have to do is install Ubuntu right over Mint by selecting the partition that Mint is on.

Comment: FYI:  I mention installing Ubuntu over Linux Mint in this *answer* where I use an *unclean* (repair/re-install) so parts I wanted remained.  I didn't use a *format* or *clean* type install as I decided I liked some parts of the install & wanted them to survive, but I also mention deleting other parts to ensure the parts I didn't want would not survive.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the Mint partitions (this will ERASE Mint), in the screen that you described in your question you have to select the option "Something Else", then:

- Select the ext4 partition
- Set the mount point to `/`
- Flag the `format the partition` option

If my memory assist me good enough the swap area is auto-detected.

**In the `something else` screen you have a mini-gParted during the installation, so pay attention on what you're doing.**