# Swap out one distro in a dual boot setting for another, without affecting the second OS?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu installed, alongside windows being dual booted. I was trying it out as my main distro and it *sucks.* I'd like to keep the windows install, but replace the Lubuntu install with Xubuntu.

Someone suggested that I manually partition it, but I don't know how to do this. They also suggested that arch might be easier since everything is manual, even installing the bootloader. I'd need help on the first and would like to avoid the second.

Comment: The current partitions can be reused. Choose "something else".

Comment: Since Lubuntu and Xubuntu have over 90% of the same packages, there is no need to reinstall anything. You can if you wish, of course, but there is no *need* for it. If you are going to dual-boot, you will need to learn partitioning sometime soon.

Comment: You've not provided any release details, but as the prior comment says; you can install `xubuntu-desktop` on your existing system and then at next logout you'll have the option of using a Xubuntu session instead (as you didn't provide release details; questions/options will vary but effect is the same). You can also use Xubuntu (you didn't provide release details so this is generic) to replace your Lubuntu system (likely recognized as Ubuntu, dependent on *unstated* release) so no partition changes are required; `ubiquity` the installer can do it. Windows isn't touched by these choices.

Comment: Please note:   using a different option on the installer can erase both systems in my last comment; as you gave no specific (release) details my advice was generic, so backup first... it's easy for us humans to make a mistake by selecting or failing to un-select an option and realize the mistake only afterwards... ie. backup any data you need to keep first...   (with re-install option; the switching desktops is just package changes and windows is not impacted at all, neither is boot so no change impacting windows will occur)

Comment: @guiverc I am now setup, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Mint with Ubuntu in dual booting system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705632/replace-mint-with-ubuntu-in-dual-booting-system)