# Uninstall Linuxfx

Tags: uninstall

I have Linuxfx running on a partition of an SDD drive but I would like to replace it with Ubuntu and KDE plasma. (I have windows 10 running on a different partition of the SSD so I don't want to simply delete the partition where I have Linuxfx because I would lose my MBR for Windows 10.) How can I best proceed? Thanks if you have time to answer.

Stevie

Comment: I install one OS over another on a dual-boot system, at least 45 out of 52 weeks per year doing as part of a QA-process (ie. *Quality Assurance* testing of Ubuntu & flavors). The installer will do whatever you tell it to, however the MBR is usually overwritten by whatever OS is last installed (as it updates the boot system so all OSes are offered); but this is easily rectified post-install, but MBR can be backed up if you wish, or you can trick the installer to not write MBR (for some releases but you didn't provide that detail). You also didn't specify uEFI or CSM though maybe implied legacy

Comment: @guiverc I see the need for a new answer to this general topic here, but I'm not sure about where it should be posted. Please consider posting an answer to this topic somewhere on Ask Ubuntu and inform me if you post it.

Comment: ack @karel, an updated answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way maybe appropriate; and I'll *aim* to write something later..  ie. it's the how to perform the upgrade/repair option that no longer exists on `ubiquity` that I use (*the code is there, it's what I often comment about that triggers that install option*).  I can include examples of other OSes too (Fedora/OpenSuSE/Debian) as it makes only minor difference if it wasn't a Ubuntu system (but still GNU/Linux on compatible *fs*)

Comment: @karel, answer put on ^ question; it's too wordy.. (more an essay/opus).   I'm not sure it contains that much more than Jorge Castro's answer though, just contains more talk of non-Ubuntu (Linux Mint, Debian, Fedora, OpenSuSE) & some details of what I do; alas essay format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who offered good advice. Particularly helpful was [Replace Mint with Ubuntu in dual booting system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705632/replace-mint-with-ubuntu-in-dual-booting-system). Coming from MS I am not used to talk of mount points. All went well with the reinstallation. Linuxfx is now gone and replaced by Kubuntu and KDE Plasma. It's faster than Windows 10 or 11 and has a nice interface.

Comment: Is your unregistered Ask Ubuntu user the same person as Stevie who asked the main question? Please reply. If so, I will ask a moderator to have your two Ask Ubuntu accounts merged.

Comment: Is your unregistered Ask Ubuntu user the same person as Stevie who asked the main question? Yes. Thanks.

Comment: @user1667297 If you wish to join the 2 accounts visit here: https://askubuntu.com/contact while logged in as either and select: ‘I need to merge user profiles’. SE staff will contact you, verify the details and then merge.