# How to reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, reinstall

I used to run Windows 7 on my laptop and over time it got very slow, so fairly recently I installed Ubuntu on my machine and it was all good, untill I deleted Python 2.7 and downloaded Python 3.6, and then suddenly terminal, Ubuntu Tweak Tool and many other programs wouldn't work. I even asked a question here on ask Ubuntu to fix the issue but nothing worked. I decided to reinstall Ubuntu because I can no longer use Ubuntu, I tried searching but couldn't find any solutions online, so how exactly do I reinstall Ubuntu? I have the Ubuntu ISO on a flash drive, also bare in mind I'm very new to Linux and know only a few commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way)

Comment: Did you try to reinstall python 2.7?

Comment: Just go through the same process you did before,and when the installer Gives you options,choose the one that says "remove Ubuntu and install Ubuntu in it's place".This will format the entire drive,so make sure you back your data up on another HDD,preferably external,and disconnected  when you do the reinstall.

Comment: Just to note, Python 3 was probably already installed. It's in the `python3` package, and you run `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: @Bob When I insert the flash drive and reboot the computer and press hold shift it doesn't show the option to boot with USB

Comment: You may have to go into BIOS and check the settings.Really old computers do not have capability to boot from USB.In my oldish laptop it was in boot options,F9,but every brand is different.