# Why am I getting a error icon at the top

Tags: 16.04

Why am I getting this error please answer me

[image]

Comment: Something is wrong with `Software Updater` or your package system. Fixing it can be a little tricky, and even once fixed, the icon will not change immediately. Open Synaptic, fix broken packages, and also reload (fix any errors displayed). See if that does it.

Comment: OMG..! I can't remove it :c

Comment: And also I cant install any software please help me

Comment: Did you use Synaptic to fix broken packages? What happens when you try to install any software?

Comment: First of all I can't even install Synaptic....While I am installing that , That's not getting installed

Comment: First of all I can't even install Synaptic  or other software...While installing that...that is not installing....pls help me by giving any help I need to install many software for my profession

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: The package locales needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
This is the reply for that

Comment: You may need to reinstall Ubuntu. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: and also please help me to reinstall

Comment: Backup your important files first, then https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation and https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way

Comment: but I don't know to go for installation type option

Comment: I have successfully reinstalled my ubuntu and also upgraded to 17.04 thank u so much for your help