# Upgrade from outdated distribution

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, lts

I have a PC with a Lubuntu Groovy 20.10. Now I want to reactivate this PC. The lifetime of the distribution has expired. Any try to update software fails. It was not a LTS version, so it happened. I'm out.

Is the only way to a current version a backup all files in the personal directories, get a list of installed software and perform a complete new installation?

How can I update to recent version, preferable a LTS version?

**Edit**
I got the hint to read [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). It looks like to give a great answer. But the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

fails with the error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
OK:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
OK:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                        
OK:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                
OK:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-old-releases InRelease 
OK:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Fehl:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-old-releases Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
E: Das Depot »http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-old-releases Release« enthält keine Release-Datei.
N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
```

roughly translated as

```
Reading packet lists ... done
E: The repository »http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-old-releases Release« doesn't contain any Release-File.
N: An update from such a repository can't be performed in a secure way, it's therefore deactivated.
N: You find further details about creation of a packet repository and the user configuration in the manual page of apt-secure(8)
```

The error messages come from `sudo apt-get update`. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: It maybe easier to backup your data and install a current version. The 404 error may be a temporary outage. Try again later.

Comment: Consider fresh installing Lubuntu 22.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way)

Comment: I'll suggest you read my answer in the duplicate I marked.. I mention "*one flavor in particular*" which is actually Lubuntu. The install I'm suggesting is called "*Install using existing partition*" in Lubuntu (our [22.04.2 QA checklist can be seen here](https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/release-team/testing-checklist/) and you can read https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743 to help understand it; that doc is intended for QA-testers (not end-users) but I'd expect still helpful.... or answer I suggested on this site via duplicate

Comment: Your sources are incorrectly the release is/was *groovy* and not *groovy-old-releases*.   Use an LTS release in future; as 20.10 was the first release on the two year *development road* towards 22.04, with the *supported* upgrade to the next release (ie. 20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04).   Upgrades to 22.04 are available from the prior LTS (20.04) or from the end of the current cycle (21.10); you can jump from 20.04 to 20.10/21.04/21.10 then all releases but not early-mid-cycle to end-cycle as you are attempting... Did you read the changes in release notes too?

Comment: Also backup any data you value... as installs of any type can destroy data, and the re-install I mention requires you to correctly select for re-use your existing partition(s) & ensure you don't format... If you format you'll get a clean system without data; it's the lack of format (*on existing partitions*) which triggers this repair type installation.

Comment: Since the sources are incorrectly configured even if I restore the previously save configuration file, I decided that my system is not able to be upgraded. I deleted Lubuntu, installed Lubuntu Jammy LTS 22.04 and restored my home directory backup. Now I setup a fresh set of applications.

Comment: Given you restored your home directory from the older release, check you didn't restore the openbox settings from *groovy* (20.10) as per https://lubuntu.me/jammy-1-released/ (See the *Upgrading Lubuntu to 22.04 LTS* section as you will most likely have overwritten the 22.04 setup) FYI: A re-install without format would have also re-installed your previously *manually installed* applications too; instead of you needing to install them manually.

Comment: The installer failed to install without re-format. There was "not sufficient space". The hard disk was filled with less than 25%, so i can't guess the reason. Well, now get I a new set of programs. Some unused will be wiped not. That is maybe the right way. At least this doesn't cost so much time to frickle with the update way to go. I did not see a chance to fix "Your sources are incorrectly".