# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 because it asks about non-existing ppa

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, ffmpeg

When I am trying to upgrade Mate Ubuntu 16.04, the process stops at command

```
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade
    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/fontconfig_2.12.6-0ubuntu2~16.04.york0_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
```

I looked at "solutions" which point out to following commands,
but they fail with outputs listed below:

```
    $ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
    Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                            
    Err:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                
      403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
    
    $ sudo ppa-purge ppa:launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11
    Updating packages lists
    
    W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
    Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
    
    $ sudo apt-get remove http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3'
```

I already tried this, but no success `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:launchpad.net/~jonathon`

Some suggest that "This question already has answers here:"
"What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file? (5 answers)"
However none of 5 answers there solve the problems. Indeed:

**Answer 1:**
Remove the PPA for an older release. For this example:
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3

--- Problem:  This does not help. Output of command is:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
[sudo] password for stan: 
Updating packages lists
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1624268195  KEYEXPIRED 1624268195  KEYEXPIRED 1624268195
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.jitsi.org stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B4D2D216F1FD7806
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Failed to fetch https://download.jitsi.org/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B4D2D216F1FD7806
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1624268195  KEYEXPIRED 1624268195  KEYEXPIRED 1624268195
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
stan@ubu:~/ww$
```

**Answer 2**
Remove the PPA with the line:

--- Problem: Thank you muru. I already noted in original question, this fails. Output is:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~jonathonf/ubuntu/ffmpeg-3'.
The user named '~jonathonf' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/ffmpeg-3'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'ansible':  Ansible
 * 'atslang':  ATS2 programming language
...
```

**Answer 3**
Yes, unchecking some tick boxes for Trusty Media and mc3man under
System Settings > Software and Updates > Other Software
did the trick. ppa-purge didn't work for me.

--- Problem: I don't see Systems Setting in Mate Ubuntu and don't
have such program mc3man to go there and "uncheck".
When trying to install it, it fails:

```
$ sudo apt install mc3man
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mc3man
```

**Answer 4 and 5**
prompt to contact an author or gamble on old package.

That will be not logical. The solution should lie in simple logic, if there is no ppa, then there should be a way to tell Ubuntu that we don't want this ppa.

Looking in repository, "https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf" shows that yes, there is no ffmpeg 3, only ffmpeg 4.

We even did uninstall ffmpeg from this PC, but "upgrade" still asks for ffmpeg.

What can be the solution? Ubuntu model of upgrade is to go
from version to version, therefore it must be irrelevant is 16.04
outdated or not. This question is not about stopped support, but
about legal procedure of upgrade.

Thank you.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Ubuntu is architectured to make people able to upgrade from one release to other. This procedure itself is a core of Ubuntu frame work and is irrelevant to which version to upgrade. Because this procedure does not work in given case, it does not matter is 16.04 outdated or not.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note only *standard* support releases of Ubuntu are on-topic, that means 20.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS, 22.10 & 23.04 currently. A standard PPA account can only build for those releases too (*such that PPAs get stale for non-standard support releases unless the builder takes steps to improve their account from a standard account*) thus issues with PPAs are expected for EOSS releases; and your question is specific to a problem created by using the EOSS release.

Comment: [Use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163224/158442) instead of `ppa-purge` here.

Comment: The answers for *duplicates* apply for *supported* releases, which you're not using. Recently Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached EOSS and is now the latest EOSS release (*taking that state from xenial which is why you have extra problems now due to chosen release*), but EOSS releases & complexities are off-topic here.  You need to consider your EOSS release in reading the answers adjusting accordingly, including that *bionic* is now the latest EOSS release that bumped yours into its now older status.  You're off-topic here regardless.

Comment: FYI:  I upgraded a *xenial* system only a couple of months ago (*had to do it before 18.04 went EOSS as I didn't want the added complexity myself! also others on this site had reported problems thus I used my system to see*), expecting problems (*I had none*) where my plan was just to *upgrade via re-install* which is super-easy for *flavors* like Ubuntu-MATE.  If it was me, I'd use a variation my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 which is what I really intended to do for myself as it's so fast! (ie. 16.04 to 22.04)