# I have an installed ubuntu 22.10 and want to install 23.03 over it, maintaining my /home and desktop

Tags: system-installation

My existing dual boot ubuntu/windows has a separate /home partition, /swap and a /data partition, along with the partitions windows installs.

The above is on one nvme ssd and a second nvme ssd has a /games folder.

If I take the live usb ubuntu option and install 23.04 will I be able to keep my /home partition and desktop?

Comment: First you must have backups of Windows & Ubuntu. If you choose the Something Else install option, you choose existing / and existing /home (and must NOT format it), it auto finds swap. Save fstab entry for mounting data partition and add that back into new fstab with new install.

Comment: Thank you oldfred, I will do that. Gparted shows an entry /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell partition and I had never seen that before. Will it auto find it too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way)

Comment: Your details are *unclear: Ubuntu had no release in 2023-March (23.03) so are you asking about Ubuntu or some other system.  I have a Lubuntu *kinetic* system here that I no longer have need for (already a *lunar* or 23.04 on that box) so I'll re-install *non-destructively* with Lubuntu *mantic* when I have some time as a QA-test install; I expect my data to exist post-install, my *manually installed* apps to also be re-installed (ie. *I'll start `clementine` or a non-default music player & play my music as I assess install*) and my box doesn't have separate /home partition either!

Comment: Note:  the results will vary with 3rd party applications (*ie. it'll work with the 3rd party that packaged to allow it to work; and fail it the packager didn't consider upgrade!*) and I had less than consistent results with Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop in QA (*I had it both work, and some installs where my additional packages did not auto-reinstall!*) but I suffered no loss of data even on less than ideal QA tests; but I can't recall which installer worked best (23.04 Desktop offers `ubuntu-desktop-installer` & `ubiquity` options!) except I had no issues with *flavors* using `ubiquity` or `calamares`.

Comment: FYI:  In your comment/question to @oldfred, I ignore any entries relating to *snaps* with regards mounts.. They're used to achieve the *container* model that *snap* packages use; however if I load `gparted` it does **not** see any such re-mount.. but I see multiple if I look via `mount`.  Also note:  my comment/dup-link is **identical** to what oldfred suggested anyway  (*additional add:  on a number of non-destructive re-install of Ubuntu Desktop lunar, I enabled universe prior to starting installer; but I can't recall how that interacted with results mentioned in prior comment now sorry*)