# I have lots of unmet dependencies. How do I fix them

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I tried to upgrade the ubuntu version from 20.04 lts to 22.04 lts. I had a power failure in between. After a restart I don't a gdm or a gui. Only the tty terminals are available. I have tried a lot of ways to fix its for the last 6 hours. Now I found a command to check all my missing dependencies. Its a scary list. I can't put the list here. As I'm typing this from my mobile. I think the error has caused due to version difference so I changed the jammy links to focal in sources.list The problem is I'm am not having a gui now. If I try to install desktop or gdm or whatever it is showing missing dependencies. I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: unmet dependencies is usually caused by a non-standard or non-matching software source(s) in sources.list (e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list`). You can't mix software sources like that from focal after you already upgraded to jammy. That sort of mixed Ubuntu versions software sources OS is called a Franken-Debian system.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the Debian *deb* package tools, which will automatically upgrade to newer/later versions from your sources, if you change the sources from *jammy* to *focal* which is an earlier version; no package downgrades can occur if you've already started any upgrade; as *deb* package tools will only automatically upgrade to newer/later packages.  The method backwards will require re-install (or restore from backups).

Comment: Maybe useful is my answer on this post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way  (*my answer even mentions going backwards to an earlier release; though I'd use it to re-install jammy or 22.04 usually; in fact often use it as it's faster than the release-upgrade process; though the process is only QA tested with official Ubuntu repository software, so it may/may not handle 3rd party depending on if the 3rd party packaged for it to work*)