# Upgrade not working something wrong with python

Tags: upgrade, python

Hello about two years ago I tried updating python and something went very wrong. I am now trying to update my distro and I am running into a bunch of problems. I don't use this laptop often and I don't know Linux all to well. I have been checking the forums but so far nothing has solved my problem. I have gathered some information and I hope I have enough to properly relay my problem. It seems that perhaps the environment variable got deleted. It also appears I have multiple python versions installed and I tried to set aliases a few years back. But I clearly broke something because the terminal doesn't work and I can't update my ubuntu version.
Hopfully there is enough information below to help resolve my problem of trying to upgrade my distro version and getting python working again.

My ubuntu version

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Commands like python, python3, and xterm return `Command not found`

var\log\apt\term.log

```
Log started: 2023-08-28  12:04:52
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
y(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 614694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/0-python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../1-python3-mako_1.0.7+ds1-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-mako.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-mako.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-mako package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/1-python3-mako_1.0.7+ds1-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-mako package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-mako.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-mako.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-mako package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../2-python3-pil_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-pil:amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/2-python3-pil_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-pil:amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-pil:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../3-python3-pkg-resources_39.0.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-pkg-resources package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/3-python3-pkg-resources_39.0.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-pkg-resources package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-pkg-resources package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
y
Preparing to unpack .../4-python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.29_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-problem-report package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/4-python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.29_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-problem-report package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-problem-report package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../5-python3-protobuf_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-protobuf.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-protobuf.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-protobuf package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/5-python3-protobuf_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-protobuf package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-protobuf.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-protobuf.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-protobuf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../6-python3-uno_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-uno package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/6-python3-uno_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-uno package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-uno package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../7-python3-louis_3.5.0-1ubuntu0.5_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-louis package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/7-python3-louis_3.5.0-1ubuntu0.5_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-louis package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-louis package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/0-python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/1-python3-mako_1.0.7+ds1-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/2-python3-pil_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/3-python3-pkg-resources_39.0.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/4-python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.29_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/5-python3-protobuf_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/6-python3-uno_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/7-python3-louis_3.5.0-1ubuntu0.5_all.deb
Log ended: 2023-08-28  12:04:56
```

Here is the history log around the time I broke it:

```
  172  sudo apt install ruby-full
  173  ruby --version\
  174  ruby --version
  175  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  176  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  177  brew install gcc
  178  echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /home/brittany/.profile
  179  eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
  180  brew install gcc
  181  brew install sdl sdl_mixer sdl_sound sdl_tff
  182  brew install sdl sdl_mixer sdl_sound sdl_ttf
  183  pip3 install pygame
  184  pip3 install pgzero
  185  gedit ~/.bashrc export PATH=/home/brittany/.local/bin/:$PATH
  186  gedit~/.bashrc export PATH=/home/brittany/.local/bin/:$PATH
  187  gedit~/.bashrc
  188  gedit ~/.bashrc
  189  source ~/.bashrc
  190  idel3
  191  idel
  192  idle
  193  sudo apt update
  194  python3
  195  python3 --version
  196  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
  197  sudo apt update
  198  python3 --version
  199  apt list | grep python3.10
  200  sudo apt install python3
  201  python3 --version
  202  sudo apt install software-properties-common 
  203  sudo apt --only-upgrade install python3
  204  sudo apt install python3.10
  205  python3 --version
  206  sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
  207  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
  208  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2
  209  sudo update-alternatives --config python3
  210  python3 --version
  211  pip
  212  sudo apt remove --purge python3-apt
  213  sudo apt autoclean
  214  sudo apt install python3-apt
  215  pip
  216  sudo apt install python3.10-distutils
  217  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  218  sudo python3.10 get-pip.py
  219  sudo apt install curl
  220  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  221  sudo python3.10 get-pip.py [B
  222  IDLE
  223  python
  224  python3
  225  idle3.10
  226  idle3
  227  sudo apt install idle
  228  sudo apt install idle3
  229  idle3
  230  idle
  231  idle3
  232  python3
  233  idle
  234  idle3
  235  dpkg -L idle3
  236  sudo apt-get install idle-python3.10
```

list of installed python versions

```
ls /usr/bin/python*

/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6m
/usr/bin/python3m
```

Here is the $PATH

```
echo $PATH
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/brittany/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

.bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

var\log\apt\term.log when trying to remove python3.10

```
Log started: 2023-08-28  14:43:48
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 614694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pil_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-pil:amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pil_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-pil:amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pil:amd64.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-pil:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.29_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-problem-report package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.29_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-problem-report package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-problem-report package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-uno_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-uno package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-uno_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-uno package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-uno package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-louis_3.5.0-1ubuntu0.5_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-louis package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-louis_3.5.0-1ubuntu0.5_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-louis package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-louis package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb
Log ended: 2023-08-28  14:43:51
```

Comment: Are you open to the simple, fast solution of backing up your data and then reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried `sudo apt-get autoclean autoremove update`

Comment: It looks like your system is potentially using Python 3.10 and not system python for apt calls.  Temporarily remove your shell environment changes in your .profile and bashrc and then start the whole process over.  **Changing the python your system uses is exactly why this is broken.**

Comment: Also maybe remove all python3 installs and just re-install just python3 - which will be the native python version for that distro. Your environment looks fine btw.

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get autoclean autoremove update` and it cleaned/removed  some python packages. But I still ran into issues when trying to upgrade the distro version. The errors can be seen in the term.log above here's a snippet:

`dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-awgn7N/0-python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: py3compile: not found`

Also commands like python, python3, xterm return command not found

Comment: @ThomasWard When I try to remove python3.10 using `sudo apt-get remove python3.10` I get virtually the same problem when trying to update my distro.
`Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found`
Ill post a the full log in the above post.

Comment: If you enter `python3 -V` what do you get?  If it's something different to what a 18.04 or *bionic* system should get, you'll be unable to *release-upgrade*, and your default python3 needs to be restored.  Your command history shows you ran version many times, but you don't show what it's presenting currently (*and as 18.04 is EOSS, I don't know what it should present any longer either*)  -- reinstall maybe easiest fix unless you can revert your changes

Comment: Download the ISO of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and perform a fresh installation. It would be much easier and faster.

Comment: @guiverc when I enter `python3 -V` i get `command not found`. Does this mean there is a environment variable issue?

Comment: `python3` will cause python to run with the option of `-V` which will return the version of the *default* on your system.  This *default* should **not** be changed if you want Ubuntu tools to work (including `apt` & in this case `do-release-upgrade` or any other part of [Ubuntu release upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tools). You've made changes that you'll need to reverse BEFORE you can use those tools; but with 18.04 being EOSS many of us can no longer be helpful you as we're no longer using it (& many tools only show supported versions thus not 18.04)

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/ shows the EOSS of Ubuntu 18.04, with [*warnings* of that posted six weeks prior to the EOSS occurring](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/), and that is only an example (it's propagated to many sites, blogged many places..).  Once EOSS is reached, those later releases lose access to reading details for ESM release (eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/ doesn't include it) thus we're limited unless we use 18.04

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS tells you it is the 2018-April release (*given the year.month format of Ubuntu release*), thus calculating the 5 year EOSS is pretty easy; 18+5 = 2023.April; thus if you'll need help; plan to upgrade before that EOSS is reached. As you missed that, I'll again recommend backup data & re-install. If it's a desktop system it's actually pretty easy (eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 maybe helpful) though yes more complicated if 3rd party software, OR you're asking about a Server system, or server apps)...