# Ubuntu Bootable USB with installed packages

Tags: package-management, usb, reinstall

I am using ubuntu 20.04 in my system. doing my works most of the times due to some issues am unable to power ON it properly and getting file corrupt issues.

Keeping the issues aside , when this issue comes i used to re install OS again and after installing OS need to install some other packages . this I need to repeat every time .

Instead of during that , Can I take backup of my OS after full installation as media to some Bootable USB drive and when I want to reinstall OS i will plug in my USB and install OS from that . Here I need not to install the packages again .

DO we have such provision with ubuntu bootable USBs . if so please share the procedure .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but is that works for 20.04 ?

Comment: From your description, I'd be checking for hardware problems, as what you describe is either the consequence of user or external action (*such as turning the machine off uncleanly, power being lost etc*) OR failing hardware... either way if you're talking about a Desktop system you can somewhat easily re-install non-destructively a system (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) but you weren't clear with details (ie. no mention of 20.04 Server, 20.04 Desktop, 20.04 *flavor* etc)

Comment: am using ubuntu 20.04 Desktop :  ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307835/) for 20.04 and later.