# The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

I am running `sudo apt-get update` and I am getting error bellow:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease                                          
Ign:2 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                 
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
Ign:4 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:7 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:8 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.10 _Kinetic Kudu_ - Release amd64 (20221020)]/ kinetic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic universe
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic universe
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic multiverse
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic multiverse
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security multiverse

#
```

Can you help me?

Comment: why do you tag 20.04 when this is about 22.10? 22.10 went end of life July 20, 2023 so the repositories are gone and dead

Comment: Those issues are because you're not using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, at least the pasted data you provided is **not** from a 22.04 system, but instead from a system that is EOL or ***End of Life*** thus those issues are EXPECTED.  You should *release-upgrade* a system before EOL to prevent this, as this will occur anytime **after** EOL is reached, be it the next day (as with 17.04), or in a few days or weeks (as with 22.10 or *kinetic*)

Comment: @guiverc do you consider re-installing OS? to solve it?

Comment: The release is EOL or **End of Life**, so re-install it will **not** fix the issue at all, the only fix is to call *the doctor* (doctor who) or travel back in time to before Ubuntu 22.10 reached EOL (ie. before https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/).   You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system non-destructively, however its not as easy with Server systems (*if if you're using server apps on a desktop system*) & you didn't specify.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades is the official link for you issue though.

Comment: This answer I wrote (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) may be helpful if you're using a desktop system, and considering a re-install  (the box I'm using now I used that on for my *kinetic* or 22.10 system, as I already had a *lunar* or 23.04 system on this box; thus I re-install *mantic* or 23.10 over 22.10, keeping my files etc..  The official link for the 22.10 to 23.04 upgrades is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LunarUpgrades too if wanted (you may need to apply EOLUpgrades first though as you missed 22.10's EOL)

Comment: thanks, was upgraded