# After I updated my Studio install from v20.04 to v22.04 many of my apps totally stopped responding

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

After I updated my Studio install from v20.04 to v22.04 many of my apps totally stopped responding when I click on them. Including snap. I did nothing special. I let the update do it's thing. It said it completed successfully. After I rebooted many apps no longer open. Does anyone have any ideas what I did wrong and how I can correct it? Will I have to install from cold? Or is there a work-around?

Comment: If you checked the release notes prior to upgrade (https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/) you'll have read "*Due to the change in desktop environment, direct upgrades to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS from versions prior to 21.10 are unsupported.*".  Breakage is very possible, thus why your upgrade isn't supported; and you'd have noted the same if you read the notes you prior to upgrade too (ie. you'll have seen or been given a link to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades#Ubuntu_Studio_Desktops)

Answer (score 2):

If you checked the release notes prior to upgrade (https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/) you'll have read

> "*Due to the change in desktop environment, direct upgrades to Ubuntu
> Studio 22.04 LTS from versions prior to 21.10 are unsupported.*.

Breakage is very possible, thus why your upgrade isn't supported; and you'd have noted the same if you read the notes you prior to upgrade too (ie. you'll have seen or been given a link to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades#Ubuntu_Studio_Desktops)

> Direct upgrades to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 are supported from Ubuntu
> Studio 21.10.
>
> [Upgrade Ubuntu Studio 21.10 to 22.04](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/#Upgrading)

Your Ubuntu base system still offers upgrades, and it will in fact upgrade; but breakage can occur with your Ubuntu Studio desktop due to the change of documented change of desktop, and warnings from Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu switched desktop from LXDE (GTK2) to LXQt back in the *bionic* (18.04) to *cosmic* (18.10) cycle too, in fact instructions were written on how users can fix the problems, however the breakage varied on what users had installed, and some *menu* items tended to remain even following instructions, thus the result wasn't the same as a *clean* install following by restoring data, and the decision was made to not support it (just as Ubuntu Studio haven't). I performed many such upgrades, whilst some were *trouble free*, the one that mattered to me most took weeks to fix & wasn't fun

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found that caveat after I did the upgrade. Will it still work even tho I did the GUI update already? (Which, unfortunately, didn't have the warning.) I guess the worst that can happen is I run it and it gets more broken. :-) It's not usable for me as it is. A challenge for another day. The good news is best I can tell I didn't lose any data. Just the ability to access it - for now.

Comment: Your Ubuntu *base* upgraded from *focal* (20.04) to *jammy* (22.04) will work correctly, and any issues you have will **not** get worse. Any breakage that has occurred will impact your GUI or user interface only, and most effects will be *annoying* but won't harm anything in my opinion. I'm on the Lubuntu team, thus am very familiar with the LXDE to LXQt change (*I was involved in QA for it*), but I'm not on Ubuntu Studio team thus didn't QA the Xfce to KDE Plasma change.. which is why I used Lubuntu's DE change as example.

Comment: If it was my system, I'd likely remove the desktop (eg. `sudo apt remove ubuntustudio-desktop`) but not purge it, then re-install it (`sudo apt install ubuntustudio-desktop`), reboot & look. That could be done in a single command too; but I'd likely reboot after the remove & before install, running both from text terminal (ie. no GUI).   but please NOTE I've not done this with Ubuntu Studio's Desktop.. it worked at least one case of a Lubuntu LXDE->LXQt breakage, but packages installed can change outcomes (*and I've not QA'd Ubuntu Studio as stated before!*)

Comment: I believe the warning was there, alas it may have required you to click a link & scroll down to see Ubuntu Studio's warning.. as the upgrade links do concentrate on Ubuntu ; ie. link you would have seen is to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades  where the link in my answer had me add the Ubuntu Studio bit added to it (ie. you'd had to have scrolled down to Ubuntu Studio to read the bit I quoted from, but its there).  I've a 23.04/lunar upgrade to 23.10/mantic on a VM viewable here now I'm doing in QA.

Comment: In order to remove and reinstall the desktop do I need to boot into a shell or can I start up the GUI and run a shell from there?

Comment: I would use a text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4) as stated, and **not** a GUI environment (esp. one you are trying to remove!).  Recall your base (text/server) system has upgraded correctly, your issue is a broken desktop thru your choice of trying to upgrade an *unsupported* system, and using terminal (not GUI) means you're using good/trusty components. My hope is removal of the *broken Xfce Studio* GUI, then install of new replacement *KDE Plasma Studio* GUI will resolve issues (*at least many*) - but I've not QA'd this, and I'm not a Ubuntu Studio team member

Comment: I have no doubt the warning was there and I missed.

Comment: I meant to say "Do I need to boot to a command line?" I tried the ctrl+alt+F4 and I see what you mean. The only way I've been able to exit is by rebooting. Is that how it works?

Comment: ^D (or control+D) is the end-of-file character in POSIX (ie. any unix or GNU/Linux box from 1970 & later).  The ^D needs to be the first character on a line, or you can always use the `exit` command to quit the session with a command if required.  You could use `reboot` or `shutdown` commands too if that's what you're going to do next anyway.

Comment: Thanks Again for all of your help. I tried every combination of ctrl and shft-ctrl I could think of and 'exit' and 'stop' all to no avail. 'reboot' was the only one that worked to get out of the screen.

Comment: I typed in the commands as you said. Rebooting between. The system looked like it processed the delete and reinstall seamlessly. But alas it didn't work. The same apps are unresponsive. 
On a positive note all my data is still intact so my next move will be to reload the distro and restore the backed up data.
Thanks Again, I know it took quite a bit of your time and I do appreciate it.

Comment: You can non-destructively re-install a system, I've written an answer here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way) and it contains links to Lubuntu QA details that also use `calamares` ... it's my *fix* on a less than ideal *release-upgrade* & my go-to if I'm in a hurry anyway (*it's fast*).  It's best with only Ubuntu software (not 3rd party) but will work with well packaged/thought-out 3rd party too (*if packager considered the future & not just making it quick for themselves*)   *Backup first of course, easy to make a mistake*

Comment: There are added complexities to Ubuntu Studio that didn't exist in other DEs that changed desktop (Ubuntu Desktop, Lubuntu etc), and I'm not familiar with all of those.