# Reinstall from boot disk. /home on /dev/sda. How to leave untouched?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, home-directory

I have an old installation of 18.04 LTS.

- `/home` is on `/dev/sda`. I want to leave this untouched
- System and everything else is on `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and `/dev/nvme0n1p2` (swap I think)

I have a bootable USB drive with 22.04 LTS, and I want a fresh install which leaves `/dev/sda` untouched, and remaining configured for `/home`.

The installations options presented were not obvious to me - they all warned I was about to destroy all my file.

When I select "Choose Something Else", I am offered a partition editor. I've used such editors before, but I wasn't sure how to ensure that `/dev/sda` does not get destroyed.

What instructions or menu options should I be selecting?

---

**UPDATE:**

So in my impatience, I selected the option to erase Ubuntu and re-install. It felt risky, but it was the only option which explicitly told me what it intended to do. It said it was going wipe both partitions on `/dev/nvme0n1`, and made no mention of `/dev/sda`.

The result is that I now have a fresh install of 22.04 LTS on `/dev/nvme0n1`, and `/dev/sda` appears as a mounted SSD drive.

**All my data under `/home/stewart` is present, which is great!**

But now I want to tell Ubuntu to use this device of my `/home`, not the one it created under on the installation device.

---

Responding to Paul Benson, these are my partitions:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  500GB  500GB  ext4         SSD


Model: Samsung SSD 970 PRO 512GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   512GB  512GB  ext4
```

Comment: From Live Ubuntu, run *sudo parted -l* and post output

Comment: @PaulBenson  Update added.  Hopefully my impatience won´t frustrate your effort to help me. I went ahead and chose an installation option.

Comment: I found some useful instructions here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: And also here. https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/installing-ubuntu-two-hard-drives

Comment: My understanding is that *sda1* is still your 'Home' folder, as that is where you originally installed it and it was left untouched. And you re-installed your root folder on *nvme01p2* Can you confirm this? So what is your problem? Are you saying you have an additional new 'Home' folder which is now the default?

Comment: I'll add a link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 where I wrote an answer on re-installing Ubuntu Desktop systems (& *flavors*) that would allowed you to upgrade your existing system to the newer release (non-destructively). When you select "*Something else*" its more a partition viewer as you select which you want to use (*though it can delete/add so has edit functions*). If you're not happy with editing, I'd just recommend using `gparted` or other app you are more comfortable with, then use the partition viewer to select

Comment: On the new system, the *file-system table* or `/etc/fstab` file controls what is mounted & where it is mounted. You can add an entry to mount your older *bionic* (18.04) home partition so it's used instead of the `/home` directory (which will exist on the new partition of the new install; which will cause the newer directory to be shadowed. Be warned, this can be problematic in the future if you forget what you did; as you'll have two `/home` directories, though 1 will be not seen when operating, but if you use a *live* system rather than installed, you'll find both still...

Answer (score 1):

You should have (and probably should) boot from your install medium, choose the "Something Else" install option.

Configure `/dev/sda` as `/home` and (this is crucial) UNCHECK the box in the "`Format`" column for`/dev/sda`. DO NOT FORMAT `/dev/sda`.

I use this method for all my upgrades.

System configuration and customization information must be saved on `/home`, or recreated.

The Method:

- `/home` on a separate partition.
- "Something Else" install option.
- `/home` configured correctly.
- UNCHECK the box in the "`Format`" column.

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I did try selecting "Something Else", but on the next screen, there was no option to configure /dev/sda as /home, and no checkbox for formatting or not. I wish I had been able to take a screenshot.

Comment: It would never be sda as that is a drive, not a partition. But it looks like you /home is still inside your old install which makes the paths different. Better to then move /home to its own partition like sda2 and then use the link on moving /home as it assumes it is a separate partition and not a sub-folder.