# My Ubuntu Cinnamon stopped in the middle of an installation and I lost access to Network Manager

Tags: networking, cinnamon

I downloaded Ubuntu Cinnamon. I was getting packages and it stopped in the middle of the installation. Now I don't have access to the Network Manager. I'm assuming because of debconf it's disabled. It won't recognize any codes I put in the slot of packages missing. I tried to run Boot-Repair on the Cinnamon install screen from USB, but it didn't help. How can I fix it so that I don't lose all of the packages that were installed so far by the Ubuntu Cinnamon installer?

Comment: You're somewhat light on specifics in your question. Are you using Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.04? or Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.10? What package(s) were you installing when you had the problem (from Ubuntu repositories, third party? etc) and what exactly did you do?  Boot repair has been reported as having a few issues lately I've noted; but you've provided nothing clear in your specifics. You can re-install Ubuntu Desktop systems (*flavors too; in fact I find it easier on flavors!*) non-destructively, but you've not yet told us what release you're asking about.

Comment: Reinstall. That is the easiest method to fix.

Comment: In case its useful; I've written an answer on this question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) which covers non-destructive re-install of Ubuntu Desktop systems (*I last did it on my current box ~30 August 2023; of course I had backups of my data if things went wrong, as its easy to make a mistake with it, so ensure backups are good; but no data restores where necessary; but I use it rather regularly in QA so am familiar with it*)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about whether it's possible to download the missing packages as .deb files on another computer, copy them to a storage device like a USB thumb drive, tell the Ubuntu Cinnamon installer the path to the missing .deb files, and then continue the Ubuntu Cinnamon installation by installing the missing .deb files with a terminal program like dpkg.

Directly copying files from another USB drive to the Ubuntu installation USB within the Ubuntu installer live environment is not possible. This is because the Ubuntu installer live environment typically mounts the Ubuntu installation USB as read-only to prevent accidental modifications that could corrupt the installation process.

Your only viable option is to reinstall Ubuntu Cinnamon. Don't forget to check the sha256 checksum of the downloaded Ubuntu Cinnamon .iso file before writing it to the installation USB. Use an officially recommended Ubuntu installation USB creator application like Rufus in Windows or Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu to create the USB Ubuntu Cinnamon installation media.

If you have been having other networking problems recently you can speed up the Ubuntu Cinnamon installation process by not selecting the options to install third-party packages, media codecs and updates during the Ubuntu Cinnamon installation process. Instead you can install these packages and updates later after the Ubuntu Cinnamon installation is finished.