# Jammy upgrade to kinetic died leaving system in partial state, damaged boot; now software update, upgrade fail

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, lts, 23.04, 22.10

I've run 22.04 LTS since it was available. In late May '23, 7mo ago, I'd done `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to keep my system up to date.
The **22.10 kinetic** release had apparently been made available, and the system began this **upgrade**.  It **failed**, leaving a corrupted boot sector; finding my way back to bootable was painful, and I started a new job, pushing this down in priority. With the new job settling in now, I just recently am able to recover my boot, and getting back to Ubuntu.
The Ubuntu partial upgrade state & settings are a mix of disabled 22.04 & a few kinetic entries.  attempts to do apt/ apt-get/ update or upgrade, via sudo cmd or via software updater fail.  I've tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it tells me 'your Ubuntu release is no longer supported'.  (It would be good if this msg stated what release the check assessed as EOL; is it seeing 22.04 or 22.10?).  attempts to use apt fail, I believe due to the mixed up system update settings.
**My goal is to upgrade to 23.04**; given the failed 22.10 upgrade state I'm fighting, **is there a means/ process to get my system back to a 22.04 solid state?**
Is there a way to upgrade from such a reclaimed 22.04 state directly to 23.04?

thanks,

UPDATE: The boot-repair summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yCHqHMyCCk/

errors on `sudo apt update` ::

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I'd recommend to do a fresh install of either `22.04` or `23.10`. `23.04` will reach End of Life in January and you'd have to upgrade again soon.

Comment: I need to exhaust paths recovering existing setup, the time to reinstall and reconfigure, no fun.  And the failed-to 22.10 is now EOL as well. Now my system apparently thinks its at 22.10, without any 22.10 update repositories added to the updater config, no apt update/upgrade...  this is ugly!  Happy New Year 2024

Comment: Please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/590937).

Comment: i was editing prior note, sys timed out on me:  I need to exhaust paths recovering existing setup, the time to reinstall and reconfigure, no fun.  And the failed-to 22.10 is now EOL as well. Now my system apparently thinks its at 22.10, without any 22.10 update repositories added to the updater config, no apt update/upgrade...  this is ugly!  Given my partitions with linux on nvme0n1p2, efi on -1p1, home on -n1p4, will a clean install 23.10 leave my apps, their data as-is? will it not mess with my partitions? n1p1 thru n1p6?   thanks, and Happy New Year 2024

Comment: I don't see your actual product details; ie. Server? or Desktop?.  If it was a Desktop install; I'd just perform a non-destructive re-install of the Desktop release you want; which differs to Server.  As [Ubuntu 22.10 is EOL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) the archives are *dropped* for mirrors & main archive is *moved* thus errors are expected. In a number of days, 23.04 will reach its EOL & the same will occur there too, and your *release-upgrade* path will disappear.

Comment: thank you Mook; I performed the ref'd Q's top answer steps, to reaccess old releases, but the last step of do-release-upgrade fails, with "your ubuntu is no longer supported" error

Comment: guiverc, good point -its desktop.  what makes a full install non-destructive?

Comment: I wrote an answer on this question about non-destructive re-install (Upgrade/Repair installs). https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533  Note that it's only QA tested with official Ubuntu repository software, 3rd party may or may not re-install, but I'd not go to 23.04 as it's EOL warning notices went out (*last month for me*) https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/12/15/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reaches-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/  and 23.04/23.10 have two Desktop installers selected by ISO downloaded.

Comment: I'll also suggest you check what you're actually running, it's very likely you're not actually running 22.04, as your provided pasted messages only relate to *kinetic* or 22.10. If you're using 22.10; you can fix your issue by following the EOLUpgrades link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) which should then allow upgrade to 23.04, and then plan upgrade to 23.10 in the coming days.  To return to the prior release (22.04) you restore your own backups, as upgrade tools are only one-way; to later releases (backwards is manual! per package!)

Comment: @guiverc thanks, I successfully nondestructively installed the 22.04.3 over my prior 22.04 partition; now some app reconfigs, I'll be good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way)

Comment: guiverc-yes, I am grateful for your help!

Comment: FYI: *my last comment; left by the system when I close-voted the question; is mostly house-keeping for the site. This site really is a database of questions & answers; where possible existing questions are to be used - the comment created when I close-voted (as duplicate; comment readable by everyone where votes are not) to that question, which means this question doesn't need an actual answer.. I'm only a user here, not a mod though*.  You got it *solved* as I understand it, that is a key purpose though! & well done.