# Wanting to swap from Linux mint 21.2 to the latest LTS Ubuntu. I have my system backed up to an external hdd will I be able to restore from that

Tags: system-installation, files, zfs, mint, migration

Laptop is a Dell inspiron 16. 1 TB SSD 64 GB ram.

[edit] I should also add that the ssd is encrypted so I have to enter a password to boot the system and another to enter the home screen and start using the system.

... In some way? I made the mistake of using zfs the first time I set up the system, then a few months ago it just wouldn't boot anymore (which is odd for a new laptop), so I had to reinstall I did a clean install wiped the drive and used the other partitioning option (sorry I don't remember exactly what it's called).

The issue is time shift (the mint HD backup tool) which doesn't work on zfs still won't work.

This might all be completely irrelevant but will I still be able to transfer ect my mint system to a fresh Ubuntu install? Will the back up I have on my external hdd restore on Ubuntu?

I know I'll have to reinstall all my programs but I'd like to keep as much as I can.

Comment: My answer on this question maybe useful (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) but do note I don't use ZFS on desktop installs, and I've not used Linux Mint backup tools (*or `timeshift` anytime recently*) as I purposely use tools that will work on any GNU/Linux or BSD system intentionally.

Comment: Thank you ill check it out and update if necessary

Comment: So when trying to install I got this: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/nvme0n1p2 - - Device or resource busy. This means Linux won't know about any changes you made to /dev/nvme0n1p2 until you reboot - - so you shouldn't mount it or use it on any way before rebooting.  What exactly does this mean? Also it froze at this screen. And I have to REISUB out of it.