# How to Downgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: downgrade

Can anyone please explain how to downgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 20.10? I do not know the commands to downgrade from 22.04 to 20.10, and are there any problems that occur if we downgrade please let me know

Comment: There is no *downgrade* option, you have the option of restoring your backups OR re-installing the older release, either way Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL & thus *unsupported* here as off-topic.  Ubuntu 20.10 had a single *release-upgrade* option anyway; to the next release which was 21.04 anyway; 21.04 likewise only to 21.10...  and not to the end of the two year *development* cycle (20.10, 21.04, 21.10 & 22.04 being the same full two year development cycle which ends in the LTS)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to downgrade? If there is any issue with 22.04, we can help troubleshoot it. Note that 20.10 has reached end of life, and will not receive upgrades, and may contain security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I would **not** recommend this option (especially not to 20.10 or any EOL release), but you can re-install *non-destructively* Ubuntu Desktop systems, which includes going backwards (*to an earlier release*) however there are many potential complications when going backwards. You didn't specify if desktop or server install; but I write about *non-destructive* re-installs in this answer ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 ) and do mention going backwards too (*though only touch on it & the 'homework' you should perform first*)

Comment: Rather than going back to 20.10; IF you're using a Desktop system, you could consider going back to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.... but what @ArchismanPanigrahi suggested (in the *XY Problem*) is what I'll suggest exploring FIRST !! If you're not aware of what I'm *touching on* here though (non-destructive re-install) you'll likely not know how to predict & plan for backwards problems should they occur... also my answer doesn't touch on 3rd party apps (*as they vary on packager/source differing to Ubuntu repository software in rules*)