# multi-booting with a mix of 32/64 OS-es

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 64-bit

I use 32-bit versions of Lubuntu and Windows on my AMD Phenom II X2 555, 32/64-capable PC.

If I update Lubuntu to a 64-bit version, will I still be able to boot both OSes?

[If it is relevant, the Windows boot option is itself a fork to either Win2k, 32bit or W7, 32bit - and, for driver-availability reasons, I don't want to change either to 64bit.]

---

I've attempted to add Lubuntu 22 to a hard drive that already had W7 32-bit on it.  It didn't work.  Then the hard drive I'd perched on top of the PC slid off the PC and struck the PC's monitor screen.

Getting to be a rather expensive experiment!

Thanks for your thoughts.  I'll pause the experiment.

Comment: You cannot *update* a *armhf* (32-bit ARM) or *i386* (32-bit x86) to *arm64* or *amd64* respectively; to change architectures requires a re-install

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *update* a *armhf* (32-bit ARM) or *i386* (32-bit x86) to *arm64* or *amd64* respectively; to change architectures requires a re-install.

You can have installed *i386* and *amd64* installs on the same hardware; if the machine is capable of running both.  The same may also apply to ARM 32bit & 64bit, but I've not tested that.

For my own systems, I re-installed using the [method described in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533).

Comment: In QA-testing (*Quality Assurance*); I have boxes with many installs. As the last *i386* or 32-bit x86 install was 2020-August, it's been awhile since I've included *i386* and *amd64* installs on the same box, but Ubuntu no longer supports *i386* so not x86 32-bit are used in QA testing.  Lubuntu hasn't supported 32-bit since 2021-April.

Comment: FYI:  In "for my own systems" I mean systems I keep for myself.. Installs/systems I use in QA vary in what is done depending on what is useful to QA-test install.. I'll non-destructively re-install often so as to keep data giving the new install something to test with; but that restoring of data post-install is more common in QA.