# How to revive an os after end-of-life

Tags: upgrade, support

I've got a machine with Xubuntu 20.04.2, which I didn't use for a while and now it is about a year past its end-of-life.  It is heavily configured, so I'd like to update/upgrade it to a recent Xubuntu.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still supported; so your system will still upgrade normally (*you just won't get fixes to the Xubuntu/Xfce or universe packages guaranteed; but its still possible for a community member (MOTU) to SRU (*stable release update*) them until 2025-April*).

Your system (*once all upgrades are applied of course*) will normally *release-upgrade* to the next LTS or Xubuntu 22.04 LTS; refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades which has mention of Xubuntu too.

If you want to *upgrade via re-install*, I've written an answer [here on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) which I use to re-install unsupported releases of Lubuntu to the next *development* release for QA-purposes; though even that isn't required yet for (x)Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: FYI:  I consider a Xubuntu 20.04 LTS system now as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Xfce... ie. you're still using a *supported* system, its just no longer supported by Xubuntu  (same applies to other *flavors*)

Comment: Maybe helpful; or just for FYI.  We only recently released [Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) which of course applies to all flavors. The *testing checklist* for Lubuntu can be found here (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist/4695/1) where you'll note there is a NA or *not applicable* for upgrades from prior LTS (ie. 20.04)... but as the *author* of that checklist I can say I'd expect it to work (20.04 to 22.04) for Lubuntu & Xubuntu too, we just don't *support* it thus haven't performed QA testing of it (Ubuntu CI still occurs)

Comment: I've not mentioned applying normal upgrades, ie. `apt update` to updates software lists, and `apt upgrade` to apply upgrades, OR depending on what additional sources you've added an `apt full-upgrade` may be required... but I'd expect those are known.

Comment: FYI:  by "*we just don't support it thus haven't performed QA testing of it*" I was speaking as a member of a *flavor* team...  Many of us are on a number of teams (thus have different *hats*; I used a link where i'm the poster for the Ubuntu News team), with a *different* Ubuntu team 'hat' on 20.04 is still supported; why I think of Xubuntu 20.04 LTS as being Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Xfce.