# How to upgrade 20.04 enough to do a release-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying options to bring an old-ish Xubuntu 20.04LTS up to 22.04.  This thing has had some problems that made me very wary of problems along the way, so I did a dry run just now.

- Installed 20.04 LTS on an empty partition (without internet).
- plugged internet back in
- Booted into the new partition and did apt-get update and apt-get upgrade
- So far so good
- Tried a "do-release-upgrade" and it promptly told me to "install all available updates" and it quit.
- I tried apt-get upgrade again and it told me it did not do anything, but 36 updates had been held back.

I did not do anything else.  This all happened in the last hour, so it's not like I forgot one little thing along the way.

What's holding these back, and how do I undo it?

Comment: If you've had 'problems on the way' then you should probably consider doing a clean install of 22.04.  it's easier to do a clean install than install old and then upgrade

Comment: I have considered that, but the amount of configuration I would have to reconstruct is truly daunting.  There's about 20 years of background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just doing a clean installation of 22.04 instead of trying to start old and then upgrade in place. A lot more can go wrong that way.

However, if you INSIST on doing this, then replace `sudo apt upgrade` with `sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`.  This does not upgrade you to the next release of Ubuntu, but **will install any packages that require other packages and dependencies to be updated or replaced as well** and get you to the point of `do-release-upgrade` working.

**I strongly recommend you try clean-installing 22.04 first though.**

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't say I understand why dist-upgrade works and plain upgrade does not, but it's true, and at least this test run was a success.  Now on to fixing my system...  Whatever I do next involves a whole lot of configuration stuff, and the path I'm choosing has the least known unknowns.

Comment: The `apt dist-upgrade` is closest to `apt full-upgrade`.  If you read the man page (ie. `man apt` ) you'll read "*full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole*" ie. it catches what `apt upgrade` does not.. To read on `dist-upgrade` you'll need to read the `man apt-get` manual page; but it's performing an `apt full-upgrade` in `apt` terms... ie. "*dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages*"

Comment: FYI:  I'd personally use a *unclean install* so my *manually installed* packages re-installed automatically during a re-install of 22.04 as per my answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1505594/how-to-revive-an-os-after-end-of-life/1505595#1505595 on an earlier/similar?? question you asked.