# Error when updating ubuntu 23.10 from 22.10

Tags: 23.10, 22.10

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife


= Welcome to Ubuntu 23.10 'Mantic Minotaur' =

The Ubuntu team is proud to announce Ubuntu 23.10 'Mantic Minotaur'.

To see what's new in this release, visit:
  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ManticMinotaur/ReleaseNotes

Ubuntu is a Linux distribution for your desktop or server, with a fast
and easy install, regular releases, a tight selection of excellent
applications installed by default, and almost any other software you
can imagine available through the network.

We hope you enjoy Ubuntu.

== Feedback and Helping ==

If you would like to help shape Ubuntu, take a look at the list of
ways you can participate at

  http://www.ubuntu.com/community/participate/

Your comments, bug reports, patches and suggestions will help ensure
that our next release is the best release of Ubuntu ever.  If you feel
that you have found a bug please read:

  http://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Then report bugs using apport in Ubuntu.  For example:

  ubuntu-bug linux

will open a bug report in Launchpad regarding the linux package.

If you have a question, or if you think you may have found a bug but
aren't sure, first try asking on the #ubuntu or #ubuntu-bugs IRC
channels on Libera.Chat, on the Ubuntu Users mailing list, or on the
Ubuntu forums:

  http://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat
  http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-users
  http://www.ubuntuforums.org/


== More Information ==

You can find out more about Ubuntu on our website, IRC channel and wiki.
If you're new to Ubuntu, please visit:

  http://www.ubuntu.com/


To sign up for future Ubuntu announcements, please subscribe to Ubuntu's
very low volume announcement list at:

  http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce


Continue [yN] y
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [833 B]                                                                                                                 
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,267 kB]                                                                                                                        
Fetched 1,268 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                       
authenticate 'mantic.tar.gz' against 'mantic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'mantic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'kinetic' to 'mantic' is not supported with this 
tool.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 had a single *release-upgrade* path, which was to the next release being Ubuntu 23.04. Once 23.04 was EOL the *release-upgrade* was not supported & a re-install should be performed.   *Exception to this is from a LTS release to the next release if in the next two year development cycle; ie. 22.04 LTS will upgrade to 23.10; but 22.10 will not*

Comment: FYI : The message "*An upgrade from 'kinetic' to 'mantic' is not supported*" is correct; your *release-upgrade* path ended after [Ubuntu 23.04 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/12/15/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reaches-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/)   also if using a Desktop system, you can *upgrade via re-install* (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) but that won't work with Server apps or systems

Comment: A Ubuntu full development cycle runs over two years and ends with the LTS. Thus the 22.04 cycle started after release of 20.04, with *interim* releases being 20.10, 21.04 & 21.10 before the final release of 22.04 LTS. Likewise the two year cycle that will conclude with 24.04 LTS includes **22.10**, 23.04, 23.04 before finally 24.04 LTS.  If you install/run a release in that two year development cycle; you must *release-upgrade* thru all releases. You can only *skip* from a LTS from the prior cycle to the next cycle (22.04 to 23.10 currently; but it'll be 22.04 to 24.04 soon)