# Quit Ubuntu release upgrade from 16.04 to 22.04 - apt recovery?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

Somehow I managed to kill the `do-release-upgrade` from v16 to v18 of Lubuntu while it was running the package setup of postgresql, about 80% complete (old unused machine).

I managed to remove the various apt, dpkg and debconf locks and continue mostly with `dpkg --configure -a`

However, I'm now left with a problem with `lubuntu-core`.

It doesn't seem right to remove `lubuntu-core` on a lubuntu machine but that's what apt wants to do.

Does anyone know if this package was removed in v18?
Is that what this means:
[WARNING: the "lubuntu-core" package was deleted from this repository, Latest version:  *DELETED*](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/proposed/lubuntu-core) ?

I've tried `apt update` and it only suggests 8 unrelated upgradeable packages which are bionic, i.e. v18.04

Errors:

```bash
root@lubnova:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lubuntu-core:
 lubuntu-core depends on xserver-xorg-input-all; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-all is not installed.
 lubuntu-core depends on xserver-xorg-input-synaptics; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is not installed.
 lubuntu-core depends on xserver-xorg-video-all; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-all is not installed.
 lubuntu-core depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-intel is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04 which provides xserver-xorg-video-intel is not installed.
 lubuntu-core depends on xserver-xorg-video-qxl; however:
  Package xserver-xorg-video-qxl is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package lubuntu-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lubuntu-core
root@lubnova:~# apt install lubuntu-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lubuntu-core is already the newest version (0.94.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-core : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all
                Depends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-intel
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-qxl
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@lubnova:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

   ... MANY MANY PACKAGES ...

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lubuntu-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 16.4 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

If I try to install the dependencies manually, it refuses and just gives me more dependencies:

```bash
root@lubnova:~# apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-core : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all
                Depends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-intel
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-qxl
 xserver-xorg-video-all : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-video-ati
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-video-vesa
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-video-vmware
                          Recommends: xserver-xorg-video-intel
                          Recommends: xserver-xorg-video-qxl
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@lubnova:~# apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-core : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all
                Depends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-qxl
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`do-release-upgrade` appears to want to upgrade to the next version:

```bash
root@lubnova:~# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

`apt update`:

```bash
root@lubnova:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                               
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                       
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                          
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/amd64  InRelease [1,477 B]                                                   
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                  
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [118 kB]
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2,151 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [8,931 B]
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [3,045 kB]                         
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [31.1 kB]                 
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [35.8 kB]                              
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]        
Get:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [1,666 kB]
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [83.0 kB]
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [237 kB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [7,156 B]
Get:19 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [5,009 B]
Fetched 7,479 kB in 4s (1,876 kB/s)                             

(appstreamcli:17225): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:43:51.142: g_atomic_ref_count_dec: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (arc) > 0' failed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@lubnova:~# apt list --upgradeable
Listing... Done
guymager/bionic 0.8.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.7.4-2]
icu-devtools/bionic-updates,bionic-security 60.2-3ubuntu3.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 55.1-7ubuntu0.5]
iptables/bionic-updates 1.6.1-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.6.0-2ubuntu3]
libfarstream-0.2-5/bionic 0.2.8-4.1~build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.2.7-0ubuntu1]
libffmpegthumbnailer4v5/bionic 2.1.1-0.1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.10-0.1]
libgegl-0.3-0/bionic 0.3.30-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.3.4-1ubuntu2]
libicu-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security 60.2-3ubuntu3.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 55.1-7ubuntu0.5]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.32.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]
```

Comment: What is the output of 'apt update' ?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: Only a *release-upgrade* from 18.04 to 20.04 would be on-topic for this site (as earlier releases are off-topic), however 18.04 was the end of the road for Lubuntu/LXDE, as all alter releases use LXQt which was only supported (by Lubuntu) via re-install. Documentation did exist on the *release-upgrade*, but even that no longer exists (*infrastructure since retired*)

Comment: @guiverc Could you point to the T&Cs of the site that state this? As far as I'm aware, AskUbuntu is a StackExchange site and so is not affiliated or owned by Canonical, therefore whether the community decide to answer a question is surely up to them?
Also, if I manage to solve the issue, I can upgrade to the latest version, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @guiverc your on-topic link states: "unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release."

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is not a *supported* release; being only supported now via ESM/Pro as the five years of *standard support* ended in April 2023, with ESM provided by Canonical only now available for 18.04.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still within its five years; so you'd have to be on 18.04 and trying to *release-upgrade* to 20.04 to be on-topic for this site (refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ which shows 20.04 is supported until 2025-April; 18.04 EOSS link provided earlier).  I'm not a Canonical employee, but part of the Ubuntu community.

Comment: I've already said Lubuntu doesn't support upgrades from any release prior to 18.10 to *supported* systems, so even if you got to 18.04 you'd be *end-of-the-road* anyway due to desktop change (18.04 was the last Ubuntu release that packaged LXDE; it's upstream Debian now unaltered). If this is a Lubuntu (desktop) system I'd recommend what is covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) on this site, OR Lubuntu QA anyway (*it's something I use myself almost weekly*). For Lubuntu EOL see https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ 29Apr2021

Comment: I'll clarify the question to point out I'm trying to get to Xubuntu LTS. Do you work for Microsoft?

Comment: Xubuntu versus Lubuntu changes little.. as they are both *flavors* and thus have the same EOL dates (*as all flavors do; eg. see https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ and it says "29 April 2021" just as Lubuntu did*).  The only difference with Xubuntu is Xfce was still used, but it went from GTK2 (just as LXDE used GTK2) to GTK3 (LXDE *devs* abandoned GTK3 port as 'too heavy' & created LXQt using Qt5 as replacement as they blogged about years ago being much '*lighter*') where the Xfce library/toolkit change shouldn't be noticed by users (*in most cases anyway*).