# Is it possible to reinstall ubuntu 22.04 desktop over ubuntu 22.04 server and keep the existing data?

Tags: 22.04, reinstall

I realized that I've installed server by mistake.
I tried to remove server packages (ubuntu-server, sssd, them apt autoremove --purge) now it doesn't boot anymore.
Is it possible to reinstall desktop over server and keep the existing data & **settings** ?
I booted ubuntu desktop iso, but I have no option to reinstall it :(
It offers me only two options, `erase` add `something else`...

Comment: Yes you can non-destructively re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system (I write about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) on this site) however as system directories get erased; server app & global configs (*which are common on Server installs*) get erased.. so what are you trying to actually save?

Comment: Basically you reinstall without checking the format box. But if you have the server install, you can just install the desktop of choice. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel or directly: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` Desktop includes all the apps, you can just install gui. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1155961