Is that possible to repair a broken 24.04 installation?
recently I upgraded my Kubuntu 23.10 to 24.04, ~85% of the upgrade process was finished, but then something went wrong and a computer was rebooted. After that PC hung deadly after start, so I booted my PC from a flash card and tried to finalize the upgrade process via chroot, but now system reports many FAILED lines in the boot.log and runs very slowly.
Is that possible to repair the broken process (I have no 'mantic' records in the 'apt list' output) or rerun it from scratch or perhaps make a bootable flash card with 24.04 and install from it over the existing installation.
WMBR, George Hazan

The answer to your question is Yes, although I doubt that would help. Fixing such an installation is a long process that involves: 1. Making sure /etc/apt/* contains the 24.04 ubuntu repo and not the 23.10, 2. finding out the packages causing boot errors and reinstalling them. Along the way you may meet situations where dependencies chain is broken completely, so you'd have to jump around the hoops with deleting/reinstalling stuff and maybe even modifying manually /var/lib/dpkg/status to make dpkg temporarily "forget" some conflicts.

That's a lot of work, and it can't be answered in terms of a Q&A-site style because solving that requires continuous back and forth communication on different steps. So… if you feel motivated, you can actually try to salvage the situation and slowly recover the system. If you don't, then maybe it's best to just reinstall the system.

I'd recommend a full reinstall, but first use "Try ubuntu" mode and save your data, don't forget the hidden files, i.e. hold CTRL and hit H in "Files" (AKA Nautilus, gnome-files); e.g. .firefox/ can be imported to e newly installed firefox, .thunderbird/ also, in most cases. .config/ and .cache/ may also contain important files, depending on what software you use.

Yes I sure would try and fix it, in fact find most cases can be fixed (unless your issue is related to the kernel stack itself; I assume you downloaded and tried a 24.04 system in live mode to check out how it will respond with the kernel 6.8 kernel!).. but given you have issues in the release-upgrade I would not login or attempt to login to a GUI, and use only text terminal.  I'd start with basics; sudo apt update & see what is there, etc.  My fallback would be an unclean install, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533

@guiverc I hope so, because otherwise I'll have to reinstall a lot of software used for development. Right now two things make me sick most:

if I remove 'quiet splash' from /boot/grub/grub.cfg, the system gets stuck on load somewhere inside 'Begin: running /scripts/premount ...'
errors like
event8: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x7c, and key code 190: Invalid argument
If I am correct, it means that not all keyboard buttons work properly?


@Hi-Angel well, for example I see smth like that in boot.log:
Failed to start apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles.
dpkg-reconfigure apparmor does nothing. What else could be done?

@GeorgeHazan does journalctl contain more descriptive error? You may need to dig into it by trying for example to run the service binary manually to see what exactly causes it to fail. That said, based on you original problem, I'd first blindly try to reinstall apparmor and related packages. Watch out for apt/dpkg not restoring missing config files by default, you have to explicitly make it to.

@Hi-Angel, that concrete service, apparmor, fails because it conflicts with data in its directory
May 02 14:39:31 BeithHazan apparmor.systemd[13921]: Restarting AppArmor
May 02 14:39:31 BeithHazan apparmor.systemd[13921]: Reloading AppArmor  profiles
May 02 14:39:31 BeithHazan apparmor.systemd[14021]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
May 02 14:39:31 BeithHazan apparmor.systemd[14031]: profile has merged rule with conflicting x modifiers
May 02 14:39:31 BeithHazan apparmor.systemd[14031]: ERROR processing regexs for profile su, failed to load

What worked for me is, during booting you go to Advanced Options- Recovery Mode. There is an entry for “enable networking”, which worked. Then choose “repair packages”. After that it was continuing the installation for several hours, after which it worked!
