Will a fresh install of Ubuntu recognize existing non-boot RAID partitions from prior installation of Ubuntu?
I have a system with 5 disk drives.  One is the boot and system drive, the other 4 are in a raid configuration, I believe its called a Raid 0.  Something seems to have happened to the boot drive as after booting it presents a blank screen.  I can see the file systems contained on the raid from other systems, so the box itself does seem to be running.
My question is: If I attempt to re-load Ubuntu on the boot drive will it recognize the existing raid?
Edits: I believe the system to be Ubuntu 22.10.  Perhaps I did not pose the question clearly - The (software) raid system disks themselves are intact and operational.  If I attempt to re-load Ubuntu on the boot drive, will it automatically recognize the other four disks as a raid array, or is there something I can do to make it recognize the array without re-building it and starting from scratch.  That is: how resilent are raid array over a system re-load.  I did not mean for it to be an "opinion" question
Edit 2: Sorry, it is a Raid 10 configuration, not a Raid 0
Edit 3: I can not telnet, ssh, or RDP into the system.  I do have the output of the mdadm commands configuration information.  I hope that if I put a USB stick with the latest Ubuntu on it, and attempt to update the system that it should keep the Raid info and all will be fine. However if I am not so lucky and completely re-load the system, with the config info I have can I rebuild the Raid and NOT loose all the existing files on the disks

RAID0 is not resilient at all. That is my opinion. The question you asked in the title is asking for opinions. That is off topic here. The question at the bottom of the text is ambiguous. The answer is "it depends". You will have to set up the new installation with proper drivers and configurations. If is not like plugging in a keyboard or a monitor.

I have re-installed Ubuntu using hardware RAID with 0, 1, 5, 10 and had no issues in getting the system back operational.. (without loss of data too) however your question appears to be asking for off-topic Opinion (esp. in title), without Ubuntu product/release details, nor clues as to the actual RAID (software handled? hardware handled?) etc.

@user535733 - I'm sorry my question wasn't clear, I've edited it and hopefully the "resilience" is more apparent now.  Since I have no user interface to the system my choice to get the system running again is to re-load Ubuntu.  Will the raid be resilient to come back after the re-load?  Is there something written on the disks so the new Ubuntu will recognize it?

Ubuntu 22.10 has reached the end of its standard support/end of life. Therefore questions about it is off topic here. Unless you want to install a currently supported version of Ubuntu (let's say LTS ones like 24.04 or 22.04) and edit your question accordingly the question will be closed as off topic.

Since the computer is running, can you ssh into this computer from another computer? Is so, use the commands cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf and cat /etc/fstab and copy and paste the output in your question. If you install Ubuntu, these (and other) files may be overwritten (or the partition formatted). Without the contents of these files (and other) the new Ubuntu won't recognize the RAID array.

@user68186 - This is not a question about what version of Ubuntu the box is running.  It is a relatively new version, not something from the 1800's.  The question is that since I can not get any live access to the system, if I re-load Ubuntu on it, will the Raid 10 have a chance of surviving - is it resilient enough?

The answer is the RAID will go off line when you reformat and install Ubuntu. You will have to recreate various configuration files to get it back online again. It will not be automatic.

@user68186 - Will recreating wipe the existing data?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

@guiverc - I am sorry you felt that my plea for help was poorly worded.  I did load a new version of ubuntu on a usb, sadly booting the system from this then only allowed to erase the disk and put the in the new version, no choice for upgrade.  Once the system was up on the new release I google searched for articles on building the array and happily found one that mention the "--scan".
How hard would it have been for someone here to mention that ?

Later releases will allow you to upgrade an existing system, however Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop & other flavors using ubuntu-desktop-installer will force a format with install due to an issue being discovered in QA, alas too late for a fix to make it in time (forced format the workaround); refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515275/cant-uncheck-format-checkbox-on-manual-partitioning-screen-when-trying-to-r but that only applies to ubuntu-desktop-installer ISOs (as its an installer issue).  Your question doesn't mention specifics as to product/release & installer

@guiverc - I did say "a new version", but ya, should have said 24.04 - which would never make it thru all the set-up steps.  I was able to load 23.10, but it also forced erase and format.  Not sure why 24.04 would never complete but I tried multiple usb devices, multiple etcher's, and downloaded the .iso file itself a second time.  23.10 went in on the first try

23.10 would not force format if you used the ubiquity installer, nor if you used the ubuntu-desktop-installer if you'd not allowed it to update; if however you used a ubuntu-desktop-installer at 23.10 and allowed it to update prior to install; using the force format of 24.04 maybe expected (I've not tested this)... You'll note I specified restriction (forced format) as relating to a specific installer (ie. you choose installer by ISO selected at download time; 2 ISOs available for 23.10 Desktop for example.. plus flavors)

@guiverc - Well silly me.  I followed the instructions found at the Ubuntu download page:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  I downloaded the iso, used etcher to put it on the stick, then booted that.  No choice to keep the existing system.

At the download page (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/mantic/release/), you were offered two ISOs for Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop; the page referred to the ISO with ubiquity as the legacy ISO (with legacy installer)

After loading a fresh version of Ubuntu, the disks themselves "know" they were part of an array so the command:
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde

re-assembles the array with no apparent damage done, all files seem to be intact.  Edit /etc/fstab to set the mount and all is fine.
