would reinstalling ubuntu fix all system files?
During an upgrade to the latest Ubuntu version, my disk got full and lots of issues started to appear such as being unable to boot so I tried several different solutions but whilst every solution seemed to fix something, on reboot another issue appeared.
So, my question is, if I reinstall on top of my existing installation, would it replace all broken system files?
I don't care about reinstalling any apps I had before. My main concern is not to lose my /home/username folder during the reinstallation process.

whatever you do - and before you do it - make a backup of your ~/home/username folder and any other important data files on the system. Use a software tool such as Timeshift after which, you can always go back to where you are now. This Its Foss guide will be useful reading.

Time shift isn’t available to be installed from LiveCD and can’t be installed using apt even after adding the repo mentioned in question #1439039

Try this more recent Ubuntu Q&A with an accepted answer instead. There are other backup tools available - the principle remains the same.

This question is similar to: How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You're not complete with details... you've tagged multiple releases, plus a release-upgrade, however you cannot release-upgrade from 20.04 to 24.04 you tagged? You also didn't say if Server or Desktop install as that really makes a HUGE difference.  I had an issue with a 22.04 install a couple of days ago (failure to boot), and finally today fixed it via non-destructive re-install with 24.04 and didn't lose any of my files, and even had most if not all of my manually installed apps auto-reinstalled so post-install it acted as the identical system (I just re-installed a newer release)

If you're wanting to re-install 24.04; please NOTE the comment in my final answer (I've another question on this site that gives more details on the issue with 24.04 & ubuntu-desktop-installer but your question details are contradictory!) as that install type is currently disabled for 24.04 with ubuntu-desktop-installer or subiquity installs....  If you do have disk space issues though; you should resolve that first, and work out what you actually want; 20.04 can only release-upgrade to the next LTS which is 22.04.  The re-install method is easier actually on 22.04 though.

"So, my question is, if I reinstall on top of my existing installation, would it replace all broken system files?"  Yes. don't format and you'll be fine.2  things: make sure to clear up your disk.if it is full it will be full doing this. and make sure your personal files are safe.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515275/cant-uncheck-format-checkbox-on-manual-partitioning-screen-when-trying-to-r/1515281#1515281 maybe useful if you're wanting to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS using an ISO that uses ubuntu-desktop-installer

It would.
In case you have a separated /home partition you can re-install system and fix all of your issues.
So i will share a similar issue i had in system and how i re-installed it.
Make a bootable usb of an ubuntu installation
Do things normally and when you get to installation type you select the something else. You remove the old system partition and install new system on the free space you made. do not make a separated home.
When ubuntu is installed successfully you restore your old /home as your current home partition by editing the fstab
Prepare mount point
sudo mkdir /mnt/temp_home
Mount temporary
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/temp_home
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab 

Edit your fstab
Add these lines:
/dev/sdXY   /home   ext4   defaults   0   2

/dev/sdXY: Replace with your home partition's device identifier.
/home: Mount point where the partition should be mounted.
ext4: File system type (adjust accordingly if your partition uses a different file system).
defaults: Mount options (typically defaults is sufficient for most use cases).
0: Specifies the order of file system checks at boot (usually 0 for non-root partitions).
2: Specifies whether the file system should be backed up using dump (usually 2 for /home).
finally do a reboot.
