Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Desktop installer crashes
I was running 22.04.4 Desktop without problems. This morning, it asked if update to 24.04.1 Desktop and I unfortunately accepted...
The update process blocked in the middle leaving the system in a not usable state: no GUI neither network.
So, I tried to reinstall from scratch. I flashed 24.04.1 Desktop ISO on a USB stick with Ventoy. I have / /boot /home swap partitions. So, I went to manual partitioning to avoid formatting /home with my data. The install process stopped very soon, the error on the log is: verifying partition flag, expected swap, found none.
By the way, the installer is very unstable, setting the laptop in airplane mode improves stability but still doesn't install.
I am without a computer now, I only had Ubuntu, can somebody suggest how install a fresh 24.04.1 Desktop saving my /home partition, please?

Did you manually a swap partition during installation? The installer is supposed to work without a swap partition.

It's helpful if you're specific with details; you mention release details (24.01.1) but not which product (Server? Desktop?) as they use different installers. Three installers are available for 24.04.1 for Ubuntu and flavors based on ISO downloaded/used; so one option is switching to another (and package changes to achieve your unstated product post-install) but we don't know yet what you're trying to install. Mention of GUI implies a Desktop install; but it's better if we're told what you're trying to use & not guessing.

Since 22.04 Desktop installation, I already had the partitions for the following paths:  /, /boot, /home, swap. To install 24.04.1 Desktop, I go to manual partitioning, I assigned the old 22.04 partitions to /, /boot, /home, swap avoiding to flag format on /home to save my data. Is that wrong? Should not I set the swap partition?

I've experienced no issues keeping a /home partition with ubuntu-desktop-installer, though there is a known issue with keeping /home directories  (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515275/cant-uncheck-format-checkbox-on-manual-partitioning-screen-when-trying-to-r/1515281#1515281) but you do mention partition (not directory).  Did you perform ISO validation prior to write to media? and did the media check complete successfully?    (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile inc. my no upvote answer on media check)

Ventoy can compute sha256sum of the ISO directly from the USB drive. I let it compute after the first install attempt failed. The ISO sha265sum hash matches with one published on Ubuntu web site for Ubuntu 24.04.1 Desktop (64-bit). I do not have the problem of format flag for /home because, by default, it is not set on the /home folder (but it ison / , /boot and swap).

I have to admit I just tried installing 24.04.1 desktop on a fairly vanilla laptop and I gave in. Noting that I have used Ubuntu for years and before that many other distributions back to Slackware 2. It appeared to be the partitioning step that was messing with my installation, but after many attempts I gave in and installed Arch. The installer needs some TLC as there seem to be many scenarios in which it hangs without any messages. Even reading the log files didn't really help to explain the reason for the failure.

I solved the problem in two steps.
To avoid the continuous installer crashes, I booted Ubuntu from pen drive with the option "safe graphics" (it may be due to my nVidia card) after the boot I disabled Wireless/Bluetooth enabling airplane mode.
To avoid the crash during file-copy phase, I did not set the old 22.04 swap partition, I left it unused. After the installation completed, I manually formatted it as swap and linked as swap through /etc/fstab file. By the way, the installer created a 8GB /swap.img on the / which I deleted.
