How to install a linux distribution by only erasing the previous distribution?
I am a 'Fedora' user.Now I would like to install 'Ubuntu' by erasing the previous OS 'Fedora'.I have many important files in other drives.I want the data of other drives won't be erased.
Please suggest me to install a new OS without erasing the other drive's data.I don't like to backup my data in a pendrive or other storage.

You've not said what Ubuntu product you're planning on using, Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? nor release detail (different installer/ISOs are available for different releases).   I'll suggest reading an answer here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way) I wrote as I mention the migration of non-Ubuntu systems (inc. Fedora) to a Ubuntu Desktop (or flavor), but regardless I'll suggest backup your data first (even if you don't use it; it's worth having as its easy to make a mistake on installers we seldom use or have never used before)

FYI:  You can achieve what you want using the Replace partition install option, or my preference is usually the Manual Partitioning options and tell the installer exactly what you want... but how these appear depend on what Ubuntu product/ISO you use, as I'm likely using calamares install terminology (not ubiquity, or ubuntu-desktop-installer as for example the ubiquity installer ISOs will call Manual Partitioning 'Something else" but its the same, just different wording & slightly different operation  (I've ignored the subiquity installer/ISOs as you likely want Desktop)

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Preamble: If you do not like to backup your data, then it means your data have no value to you. It therefore is not a problem if you make a mistake and delete the data.
Important message to other readers: always, always make sure you have an up-to-date backup of your data before attempting a system intervention. Even if you know very well what you do, something can go wrong - user error or system error - that may cause you to erase data.
There are a few ways to proceed.

You can prepare the disk before installation using a disk partition editor (Gnome Disks, GParted). Erase the system partition of Fedora. Then run the installer with the option "Use available free space".

Alternatively, you can proceed to a custom installation. Then, you manually indicate which partition is to be used for the system.


Your other data partitions will not automatically be mounted. You can configure that in the newly installed system. With option 2, you could do that already during install time.
