upgrade from Ubuntu 22.10
I'm still working with Ubuntu 22.10. This version is no longer supported. Is there a way to upgrade to 23.04 without a complete restart?

Ubuntu 22.10 had a single upgrade path (given it was not a LTS release, but an interim release in the two year development cycle that completed with the release of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS), which was to the next release in the cycle; ie. Ubuntu 23.04.  That door however closed when 23.04 reached EOL

This question is similar to: Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You haven't said what product you were using (that can make a difference), eg. for Desktop systems you can non-destructively re-install systems which is worth considering; eg. I wrote an answer here ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 ) that I may consider; though that feature is somewhat disabled on 24.04 (with ISOs using ubuntu-desktop-installer but is available for ISOs using calamares) but could still be used to go to 23.10 though (ubiquity or calamares ISOs)

FYI:  If you want to try, the doc on EOL upgrades can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but you'll likely be told as I've already indicated  (ie. that upgrade was supported after 22.10's EOL, until 23.04 reached EOL then the upgrade is expected to be via re-install)

No, there isn't. The upgrade path to 23.04 is not anymore supported.
This is the case for any EOL Ubuntu release. If you want to update, you should do so before the version runs out of support.

I already feared this. Thanks anyway.

If this answer resolved your question, even if the answer may be disappointing, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer.
