How can I reinstall Ubuntu
I have a Dell XPS L520X that is currently running Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. I want to update to the latest version of Ubuntu, which means that I have to reinstall it. However, I am having some problems with the installation.
The first thing I tried was installing Ubuntu 24.04 from a thumb drive. I flashed it with BalenaEtcher, then inserted the thumb drive into the eSATA port and selected eSATA in the boot menu. This didn't work, as when the Ubuntu loading screen showed up, it kept flickering back and forth from the loading screen to a terminal, and not actually loading. I then did a forced shutdown, but when I tried to load from the usb drive again, it just said "Operating system not found". I re-flashed the drive, but it still said that it couldn't find an operating system on the drive.
I then looked into installing Ubuntu without using external media. I tried doing what was suggested here, but UNetbootin didn't work for me, and I was unable to create a partition, as when I tried, I got an error saying that there was no available space for primary partitions. I was creating the partition in dev/sda, not the thumb drive. I also know that I was using the tool correctly, as I was following a tutorial.
If somebody could tell me how I can overcome these problems and reinstall Ubuntu, that would be greatly appreciated.
PS: this question is different from the other questions suggested, as I do not need to use the Ubuntu minimal image (my thumb drive has plenty of space) and the problem is not that I am unaware of how to install Ubuntu, as I have successfully installed it on other computers, the problem is that the methods I have used to install Ubuntu have failed.

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You've not provided the details that I consider critical, ie. you mention a release (18.04) that reached EOSS some time ago but didn't mention which product (a Server or Desktop install). An answer I wrote here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) would be useful for Desktop installs but not Server installs. Your details are possibly a user-procedural error (bad ISO, bad write of ISO to media or invalid write method) but no details were provided on how done, nor product/release/architecture.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"This didn't work, as when the Ubuntu loading screen showed up, it kept flickering back and forth from the loading screen to a terminal, and not actually loading." Take a video with your phone and post a link so we can see it.

"it still didn't work" is too vague to offer useful advice. Try to make your description precise. Lots of accurate details.

"I got an error saying that there was no available space for primary partitions." This suggests improper use of the tool --or-- a dying and unreliable thumb drive. It's up to you to figure out which.

The first thing I tried was installing Ubuntu from a thumb drive Which version of Ubuntu did you try? Please try 24.04 in case you were trying something else.

user535733, I don't have a phone.
