Linking pre-existing home partition to new Live USB 20.04 LTS install?
I have installed Ubuntu 3 times and screwed it up 3 times trying to point the OS to my pre-existing separate home partition (sda3) named /home. It is on the same drive as the Ubuntu install (sda1).

I know the UUID for the home partition.
I know fstab needs that new UUID.
UBUNTU does not like me trying to change the name of the new
/home directory or removing it: resource busy error.
So I know I need to rename the new home to somethimg else (home_OLD say) and delete it later as I see fit.
Then make a new home directory (mkdir).
Either my sequence of events is wrong or something because Ubuntu is freezing up when I restart it.
Is there a definitive link that explains exactly how to redirect home to another partition?
I want to get this done before I start reinstalling apps so any relevant information is placed in the existing home partition and not in the new home directory.
So I am hoping to get a definitive answer or link to guide me through this process.
thanks....


Your details are unclear to me; for starters you mention Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but don't mention a product (Server & Desktop use different installers & you've not said which you're installing). I'm confused by the renaming of directories (directories are set based on $HOME or the $USERNAME you provide) and don't understand what you're trying to do, nor what you're actually doing. Use the manual partitioning mode to do what you want, or PREPARE IT BEFORE HAND & just point the installer at what you want (but directory names are preset based on values you give)

it is desktop version. I want to use the preexisting home partition i had before reinstalling the OS. how do you make ubuntu look at my home partition at sda3 instead of the blank home created during the install on sda1?

Your question mentions "trying to change the name of the new /home directory" and other details that just confuse me. Tell the installer what you want; my answer on this post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) maybe useful (if time allows I'll re-install a 22.04, 24.04 & 24.10 system using it today for QA testing purposes) which is via the "Something else" option in ubiquity used by 22.04 Desktop

since this so problematic for me i suppose just wiping the drive completely and making sda1 200 GB with HOME inside it is a workaround. I wohld rather have a separate HOME partition but these headaches are not worth it.I rarely operate in the Linux background since it runs so stable and I my elderly mind forgets things from a couple years ago.

I'll recommend you try and keep a separate home partition if you can (see the last comment in my linked answer; that issue hasn't been fixed thus 24.04 re-installs can be problematic where there no separate /home!)   I personally setup what I want in the live session BEFORE starting the installer, than start the installer & select what I setup first; so the installer is told to use what I setup  (ie. I'm not doing the setup in the installer; few of us use installers that often; thus I'm using tools I feel more comfortable with)

i prefer a seperate home but there should be a tutorial for folks likd me who rarely operate in terminal mode. Doing something like reassigning home to a new location should be fairly easy if given the steps. yoy can bet i will write everything down on paper if i ever figure it out.

This question is similar to: Keep /home directory when installing Ubuntu 14.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this site. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

When you reinstall, do not allow the installer to automatically configure the disk. On the partitioning screen, pick "custom/something else" and manually  select your /home partition. Pick Edit, choose "do not format" and set the mountpoint to /home. That is all.
From your partial and incomplete description, you are not doing this, but trying to do it later. That is the wrong way.

should the "device for bootloader installation" be the /home partition (sda3) or sda1 (/)? This is where I get confused because sda1 is where the OS is usually placed.

The bootloader goes in the main drive, not in a partition. So no number on the end.

Decided to to install OS with home residing inside same partition as OS. KISS - keep it simple stupid. I do not need any unnecesssary headaches with my limited skillset.
