How to migrate LUbuntu 22.4 @ machineA to LUbuntu 24.04 @ machineB?
I've got a low-end tablet running LUbuntu 22.04 along with some multimedia applications.
What's the easiest way to migrate everything installed there onto a new machine with a fresh install of LUbuntu 24.04?
Is there a way to just export / import everything or do I have to re-install and configure everything including LUbuntu configurations like wifi, screen savers, bluetooth etc.?

When my old system died (dell optiplex 960; dead PSU) I intended to just copy my backup data to the new replacement box (dell optiplex 7050) and if it booted use it (old box was legacy so I didn't expect it to boot on newer uEFI box) thus intended to non-destructively re-install onto it (ie. keeping my old data I'd restored!)...  I used the box for QA test installs which meant I couldn't do that; so just restored data post-install...  effect was ~same.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 if helpful

How to migrate the whole system to a new machine? see above refers to the same Ubuntu Version. However, I'm using different LUbuntu Versions on different machines. What's the easiest way to migrate everything installed on machineA runnign LUbunut 22.04 onto a new machine running LUbunut 24.04?

I don't see how Lubuntu and Ubuntu differs, and versions matter little to me too (esp. if using a calamares installer for 24.04).  Did you read my suggestion?  as whilst my older dell 960 used hdd & this newer 7050 has ssd & I copied data post-install (so as to use a QA testcase for install) the result was ~same as if I'd copied data before & non-destructively re-installed over it... ie. prior comment gives what I'd do.  (my comment was specific to Lubuntu, but applies to others too); & included links to Lubuntu discourse for more.
