Burned a Flash drive with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. It wants to slam my computer and has no provision for upgrading from Ubuntu 22 or 23
When I boot with the Flash drive with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS it brings up everything from my Ubuntu 23 in live. When i start to install it, it only gives the option of formatting my hard drive, why? Just want to upgrade to 24, and have lots of issues with my internet provider. I was able to use the torrid to get Ubuntu 24, and burn the usb flash drive.
when I try to use upgrade manager it stops and says I need a more secure internet. please help

If you have good backups, you can try reinstalling to same / (root) partition using Something Else or manual install. It will overwrite all settings, but any files you have added should remain. Still best to have good backup. https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533

This question is similar to: Can't uncheck "Format" checkbox on "Manual partitioning" screen when trying to reinstall Ubuntu 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your details are vague & inaccurate. There is no Ubuntu 23; with the year format reserved for snap only versions which come out on even years only (eg. Ubuntu Core 22 is the snap only version of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server).  You also don't specify if you're asking about Desktop or Server (assuming 22.04) as they use different installers. The duplicate link I provided applies to forced format on the ubuntu-desktop-installer which applies to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop, but that applies to specific partitioning layouts (and you gave no clues there either).  For best help be specific.

When I boot this computer with the Ubuntu 24.04 lts live usb and select "try" it comes up fine with all of my files displayed. Then if I boot again and select install, the upgrade option is grayed out and does NOT work. Next it takes me to the partition tables, which also does not work. The only option it gives is to completely slam the computer and reformat.

The ubuntu-desktop-installer has a forced format for the / partition as mentioned in the duplicate; only 24.04 ISOs using calamares installer do not force format; Ubuntu Desktop uses ubuntu-desktop-installer as do many flavors, though 3 flavors use the calamares installer that doesn't mandate format.
