Changed the root access! now unable to boot Ubuntu
I was working on some folder. I wanted to give root access to that folder. Accidently i used this command (sudo chown -R root:root /) and now i am unable to boot my Ubuntu anymore. It shows the ubuntu boot screen but i dont see the user anymore.
I was using ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop
Any help?

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but a number of apps will refuse to run if the permissions on their files are incorrect; so the effects will vary depending on what Ubuntu product & apps you're using. Restoring your file-system from backups maybe fastest, but I've written a script before that copied permissions from a backup to the production server before as the lesson that would teach me not to do it again (and be more careful)...  so you're not alone

Tried with recovery mode. No help

The command you ran have more or less destroyed your root filesystem. I'm currently looking into if this has been asked before (I'm pretty sure it has), but in any case recovery can be pretty tedious - it's probably easier to reinstall the system.

I also looked around but didnt find any proper solution. It seems reinstalling is the only option here.

I talk about a non-destructive re-install in this question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533)  ... manual solutions are very tedious.... the hours taken to write a fix for an install being done to imprint being careful into the mind of the careless one in my first comment...  but restoration from backups is the normal fix to operator error which careless chmod -R is.

You changed ownership of all files and directories in your system to root. It's quite expected that the system can't work anymore after this. There's no easy fix. If you don't have a full backup of your system, or at least another working system in the same version (then you could copy all files/dirs from that other system with their permissions to overwrite the local ones), reinstalling seems to be the only option...

That command is expected to destroy your Ubuntu system.
Use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to recover your data on to some other media (and to repair the ownership of that data).
Then reinstall Ubuntu.
It is theoretically possible to repair by tediously restoring the correct ownership of each file on your system, but nobody has ever done so and returned to tell the tale.
