Laptop hung up while upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 from 22.04. I managed to login to 22.04. How do I backup files to ext harddisk?
This problem started a week back when my Linux suggested to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 (working perfectly) to 24.04. The laptop hung up in the middle of the upgrade. I have tried numerous attempts to fix it. NOTHING worked. Now I want to transfer all relevant files to ext. hard disk (/dev/sdb1), and then reformat Linux fresh. How do I do that? Youtube sessions are not helpful. can you help?

Question 1 is, what are  "all relevant files"?

You haven't specified what product you're using, only giving release details (22.04 upgrading to 24.04).  Myself I'd just boot live media & copy (probably using rsync) to your media & update your existing backup, OR create a new backup of files that way. If your system can boot to runlevel 1 you maybe able to backup using your existing system (from terminal anyway) but I'd likely run file-system checks from live media first (esp. if you forced power off for example). We can't know what files are relevant as you've only given release details; not said what you were using.

FYI:  A common fix I use is mentioned in an answer here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) BUT I'd ensure I have backups first (of data that matters to me), and that answer may properly only work with 24.04 ISOs using calamares installer, as format is forced with ubuntu-desktop-installer ISOs (it's not as good anyway with Server or subiquity installs anyway).

This question is similar to: How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
