Can't upgrade from Kubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 nor 24.04 (Stuck in version)
So when I turn my computer on it tells me that I should upgrade, when I click ont he upgrade it gives me an error:
An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'noble' is not supported with this tool.
An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'noble' is not supported with this tool Error message
So looking around somebody said that I need to upgrade first to 23.10 and left a link to an index with different upgraders to different versions:
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
I downloaded the one for 23.10 so as to follow the update path and tried to run it after decompressing it:
sudo ./mantic
And I get these messages:
Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager
And then:
Can't install 'kubuntu-desktop' It was impossible to install a required package. Please report this as a bug using 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
The program finally leaves with the message:

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This was likely caused by:
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

I appreciate any help, I'd rather not re-install kubuntu and sorry for the formatting mistakes.
JUST TO BE CLEAR:
My intention is NOT to skip over the releases, but to fix the error that is preventing me from upgrading to 23.10, and in turn making a 24.04 upgrade impossible.

The expected upgrade path from 23.04 is to 23.10; however that upgrade path disappears when 23.10 reached EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/) so the supported path now is via re-install.   Don't delay in the release-upgrade, you had six months after 23.04 reached EOL before the release-upgrade path disappeared; you're too late now.

An answer written on this question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) maybe useful in a non-destructive re-install of 24.04, as Kubuntu is using the calamares installer..   I've used it myself to perform the 23.04 to 24.04 upgrade; however that was long ago now (when 23.04 reached EOL actually; as I didn't need another 23.10 install for support purposes) but it's an option.  Upgrades to 23.10 are no longer on-topic here as the release is EOL.

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   The supported path from 23.04 is thru 23.10; you missed that, so re-install is now the supported option

FYI:  You often need to purge 3rd party software for the release-upgrade to work; which is what the message you pasted in your question is telling you.. ("Please use the tool 'ppa-purge'")  Read the logs of the attempted release-upgrade process if you want specific packages to purge (ie. want to avoid purging all) as the release-upgrade is QA tested only with Ubuntu packages (not 3rd party; unless they packaged it for release-upgrade intentionally)    The 3rd party sources aren't the problem; installed packages being the problem don't forget  (making re-install actually faster).
